# How to insert an item into an array at a specific index?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am looking for a JavaScript array insert method, in the style of:

```
arr.insert(index, item)
```

Preferably in jQuery, but any JavaScript implementation will do at this point.

Comment: Note that JQuery is a DOM and event manipulation library, not a language of its own. It has nothing to do with array manipulation.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/ has nothing to do with the DOM or events. jQuery has evolved into a mixed toolkit for in browser JS development, leading to people expecting it to have a method for everything.

Comment: @Tim, But it's still not a language of its own (still there are some questions like "how to sum two numbers in jQuery" here on SO)

Comment: @Victor No, and never will be. jQuery was useful and relevant, but it's had its day.

Answer (score 6728, accepted):

You want the **[`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** function on the native array object.

`arr.splice(index, 0, item);` will insert `item` into `arr` at the specified `index` (deleting `0` items first, that is, it's just an insert).

In this example we will create an array and add an element to it into index 2:

```js
var arr = [];
arr[0] = "Jani";
arr[1] = "Hege";
arr[2] = "Stale";
arr[3] = "Kai Jim";
arr[4] = "Borge";

console.log(arr.join()); // Jani,Hege,Stale,Kai Jim,Borge
arr.splice(2, 0, "Lene");
console.log(arr.join()); // Jani,Hege,Lene,Stale,Kai Jim,Borge
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought I would feel stupid for asking but now that I know the answer I don't!  Why on earth did they decide to call it splice when a more searchable term was in common use for the same function?!

Comment: @tags2k: because the function does more than inserting items and it's name was already established in perl?

Comment: doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object

Comment: Splice *can* insert, but just as frequently *does not*.  For example:  `arr.splice(2,3)` will remove 3 elements starting at index 2.  Without passing the 3rd....Nth parameters nothing is inserted. So the name `insert()` doesn't do it justice either.

Comment: I think the term "splice" makes sense. Splice means to join or connect, also to change. You have an established array that you are now "changing" which would involve adding or removing elements. You specify where in the array to start, then how many old items to remove (if any) and lastly, optionally a list of new elements to add. Splice is also a great sci-fi term of course.

Comment: Could someone please tell me from a performance point of view is using `splice` good in this case? I mean, if I have an array with thousands of items and I want to insert an element somewhere between two elements, how does JavaScript update the indexes of the array from that point where I insert the item to the end of the array?

Comment: @tonix I would think that it would be an O(n) operation as it has to shift all the values belonging to the indices following the items inserted.  In the worst case (inserting an item at the beginning) that would be all of the (n) items in the array.

Comment: I understand. Can it be improved somehow? I mean, I have just found something like `creating two separate indexes placed in the middle of the array` or `rotating arrays` but I didn't understand what the author of the article meant (https://gamealchemist.wordpress.com/2013/05/01/lets-get-those-javascript-arrays-to-work-fast/), point 6 at the end and 7

Comment: I think he's talking about techniques to avoid resizing the array by keeping track of the the valid indices yourself. Unless you're facing a performance issue currently I wouldn't start trying to write your own array options.  It'ls also possible that another data structure might work better - say balanced trees - depending on the need of your application.

Comment: @tonix - Do you have an actual performance problem? If not, you're doing premature optimization, which leads to harder to maintain code with no benefit. Making splice perform well is the responsibility of the person writing the Javascript engine/library, not yours. Don't make it yours unless you have to (IE, your program is unacceptably slow unless you have some ugly hacks.)

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare As tvanfosson said, the amount of operations of splice is `O(n)`. Meanwhile, I have created a class which I call a `LinkedOrderedMap`, which allows me to insert items and keep them in order, and when I need to remove an item from the list I simply unlink the node where the item is located inside the list and tell the previous node that its next item now is the next node of the node I am going to remove. To insert an element between other elements in the list, I can use the same strategy, too.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Of course, I have to benchmark it before I can make assumptions about a performance gain, but with such an implementation the amount of required operations is constant. It doesn't matter how long the list is. I remember there was an online site where you can benchmark you JS code, but I couldn't remember the name. Could you pass me a link if you know it. I will then benchmark the code I have written against splice and tell what the results are.

Comment: @tonix - Your code is written in JavaScript and needs to be interpreted. Splice's code is likely more native.

Comment: given that the new `class` and `constructor` elements for the new EMCAScript is nothing more than syntactic sugar for existing methods, would it be too much to make an `insert` function/alias ?

Comment: Splice was premature optimization, when JavaScript got "invented". Instead of just throwing in the common "insert/remove", they took the splice function, that does both and pains every newcomer. Now everybody is used to splice and will disagree with me.

Comment: Is there a certain critereria that you would you splice instead of just `array[index] = newValue`?

Comment: @NateThompson When the index doesn't exist (i.e. it needs to be inserted between two values, not in place of a value).

Answer (score 424):

You can implement the `Array.insert` method by doing this:

```
Array.prototype.insert = function ( index, ...items ) {
    this.splice( index, 0, ...items );
};
```

Then you can use it like:

```
var arr = [ 'A', 'B', 'E' ];
arr.insert(2, 'C', 'D');

// => arr == [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' ]
```

Comment: To insert multiple items you can use `Array.prototype.insert = function (index, items) {
    this.splice.apply(this, [index, 0].concat(items));
}`

Comment: The problem with adding stuff to array is that the function will show up as an element when you do 

for(i in arr) {...}

Comment: But keep in mind that it's not recommended to extend native types since it might interfere with other code or future functionality.

Comment: Don’t modify objects you don’t own

Comment: @RyanSmith Or, with ES6, `Array.prototype.insert = function(index, ...items) { this.splice.call(this, index, 0, ...items); }`.

Comment: @SolomonUcko yeah you could tbh for ES6 I'd just do `[...arr.slice(0, index), ...items, ...arr.slice(index)]`

Comment: @RyanSmith The problem is that that has to copy the start of the array, not just the end.

Comment: @SolomonUcko that is true, if you're working with large arrays that is something to consider. For smaller arrays, I think that the benefits of immutability outweigh the negligible performance implications. Note that there is an answer here that uses this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/38181008/1221906 so probably best to provide feedback there for people that are using this approach.

Comment: Don't modify prototypes

Comment: it will implement bug in your code when other arrays may not work anymore

Comment: Modifying a built-in just to remove one parameter from an existing method for that same built-in is certainly an approach... you're literally saying either `arr.splice(2, 0, 'C', 'D')` or `arr.insert(2, 'C', 'D')`.  Just use `splice`.

Answer (score 308):

Other than splice, you can use this approach which will not mutate the original array, but it will create a new array with the added item. It is useful, when you need to avoid mutation. I'm using the [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) spread operator here.

```js
const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

const insert = (arr, index, newItem) => [
  // part of the array before the specified index
  ...arr.slice(0, index),
  // inserted item
  newItem,
  // part of the array after the specified index
  ...arr.slice(index)
]

const result = insert(items, 1, 10)

console.log(result)
// [1, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

This can be used to add more than one item by tweaking the function a bit to use the rest operator for the new items, and spread that in the returned result as well:

```js
const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

const insert = (arr, index, ...newItems) => [
  // part of the array before the specified index
  ...arr.slice(0, index),
  // inserted items
  ...newItems,
  // part of the array after the specified index
  ...arr.slice(index)
]

const result = insert(items, 1, 10, 20)

console.log(result)
// [1, 10, 20, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Is this a good, safe way to do this? I ask because this seems so elegant and concise but no other answers touch upon this. Most of them modify the prototype object!

Comment: @HarshKanchina That's probably because most of the answers are pre ES6, but this approach is very common now from my experience

Comment: This approach will always be slower and worse than splice. Don't be fooled by the pretty sugar syntax or the popularity among other misguided devs (\*cough\* gafi \*cough\*). Allocating a whole new array and discarding the old array is way slower than modifying the original array. If you need a copy, then call `slice()` before `splice()`. Never use the ES6 for such trivial things which can be done far better and far more cleanly with other APIs.

Comment: You should explain WHY you should avoid mutation. Is it slow? If so, how much slower? Is it worth the extra "hassle"?

Comment: @JackG don't forget that `slice()` will allocate a new array, and indeed, `splice()` allocates a new array too since it returns an array of the items that were removed (an empty array in this case). Running a benchmark on these cases shows that splice is quicker (by ~30%), but we're in the range of millions of operations per second, so unless your application is doing a _lot_ of these operations in a tight loop, it's not going to make any difference.

Comment: @nickf If you are splicing out a small  number of items (especially zero items) then the small array allocated by splice will be part of the young generation, which is near-zero-cost memory. In comparison, making a copy of a big array will not use new space but rather a special large object space, possibly even invoking a system call to allocate more memory if the array is big enough. Only in the specific case of splicing out the majority of a very large array might splice by slower.

Answer (score 93):

Using `Array.prototype.splice()` is one elegant way of achieving it

```js
const numbers = ['one', 'two', 'four', 'five']
numbers.splice(2, 0, 'three');

console.log(numbers)
```

Read more about [Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: As stated above, using prototype will add an extra item to the array, so the loops won't work as expected after.

Answer (score 90):

## Custom array `insert` methods

#### *1. With multiple arguments and chaining support*

```
/* Syntax:
   array.insert(index, value1, value2, ..., valueN) */

Array.prototype.insert = function(index) {
    this.splice.apply(this, [index, 0].concat(
        Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)));
    return this;
};
```

It can insert multiple elements (as native [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) does) and supports chaining:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d"].insert(2, "X", "Y", "Z").slice(1, 6);
// ["b", "X", "Y", "Z", "c"]
```

---

#### *2. With array-type arguments merging and chaining support*

```
/* Syntax:
   array.insert(index, value1, value2, ..., valueN) */

Array.prototype.insert = function(index) {
    index = Math.min(index, this.length);
    arguments.length > 1
        && this.splice.apply(this, [index, 0].concat([].pop.call(arguments)))
        && this.insert.apply(this, arguments);
    return this;
};
```

It can merge arrays from the arguments with the given array and also supports chaining:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d"].insert(2, "V", ["W", "X", "Y"], "Z").join("-");
// "a-b-V-W-X-Y-Z-c-d"
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/UPphH/

Comment: Is there a compact way to have this version also merge an array when it finds one in the arguments?

Comment: I don't understand the first result `["b", "X", "Y", "Z", "c"]`. Why isn't `"d"` included? It seems to me that if you put 6 as the second parameter of `slice()` and there are 6 elements in the array starting from the specified index, then you should get all 6 elements in the return value. (The doc says `howMany` for that parameter.) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: Actually, if I use an index of 3 or more, I get nothing in the output (case 1., FireFox) `["a", "b", "c", "d"].insert(2, "X", "Y", "Z").slice(3, 3);` => `[ ]`

Comment: @AlexisWilke In the first example I used [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method and not `splice`, which you're referring to in the comment. Second parameter of `slice` (named `end`) is *zero-based index at which to end extraction. `slice` extracts up to but not including `end`*. Hence after `insert` you have `["a", "b", "X", "Y", "Z", "c", "d"]`, from which `slice` extracts elements with indices from `1` up to `6`, i.e. from `"b"` to `"d"` but not including `"d"`. Does it make sense?

Comment: For some reason, when I go to use insert2, i get an "Expected 1 argument, but got 2" exception.

Comment: As stated above, using prototype will add an extra item to the array, so loops won't work as expected after.

Comment: @TravisHeeter "loops won't work as expected" Why? How? Give an example.

Comment: Here's the direct quote from @rep_movsd: "The problem with adding stuff to array is that the function will show up as an element when you do for(i in arr) {...} "

Comment: @TravisHeeter which makes sense, no? To iterate an array you need to use `for (i of arr) {...}`.

Answer (score 56):

If you want to insert multiple elements into an array at once check out this Stack Overflow answer: [A better way to splice an array into an array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348178/a-better-way-to-splice-an-arrray-into-an-array-in-javascript)

Also here are some functions to illustrate both examples:

```
function insertAt(array, index) {
    var arrayToInsert = Array.prototype.splice.apply(arguments, [2]);
    return insertArrayAt(array, index, arrayToInsert);
}

function insertArrayAt(array, index, arrayToInsert) {
    Array.prototype.splice.apply(array, [index, 0].concat(arrayToInsert));
    return array;
}
```

Finally here is a jsFiddle so you can see it for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/luisperezphd/Wc8aS/

And this is how you use the functions:

```
// if you want to insert specific values whether constants or variables:
insertAt(arr, 1, "x", "y", "z");

// OR if you have an array:
var arrToInsert = ["x", "y", "z"];
insertArrayAt(arr, 1, arrToInsert);
```

Comment: Wouldn't insertAt() do better to call insertArrayAt() once it has created a single-element arrayToInsert? That avoids repetition of identical code.

Comment: this is a great example of when to use 'apply'

Comment: I added a removeCount parameter to this method to take advantages of splice's ability to also remove items at that index: Array.prototype.splice.apply(array, [index, removeCount || 0].concat(arrayToInsert));

Comment: Thank alot and i use it in `qml`

Answer (score 47):

### You can use `splice()` for that

The `splice()` method usually receives three arguments when adding an element:

1. the **index** of the array where the item is going to be added
2. the **number of items to be removed**, which in this case is `0`
3. the **element** to add

```js
let array = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3']
let insertAtIndex = 0
let itemsToRemove = 0
    
array.splice(insertAtIndex, itemsToRemove, 'insert this string at index 0')

console.log(array)
```

Comment: next time read the answers please, this solution was already given. You are just repeating information.

Comment: @vdegenne when I posted this answer, I thought the other answers could be better explained. The amount of votes up is a clear indicator that the answer has ben useful for some.

Comment: Yes, explaining the meaning of the second parameter is especially helpful

Answer (score 46):

## Solutions & Performance

Today (2020.04.24) I perform tests for chosen solutions for big and small arrays. I tested them on [macOS v10.13.6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_High_Sierra) (High Sierra) on Chrome 81.0, Safari 13.1, and Firefox 75.0.

### Conclusions

For all browsers

- surprisingly for small arrays, non-in-place solutions based on `slice` and `reduce` (D,E,F) are usually 10x-100x faster than in-place solutions
- for big arrays the in-place-solutions based on `splice` (AI, BI, and CI) was fastest (sometimes ~100x - but it depends on the array size)
- for small arrays the BI solution was slowest
- for big arrays the E solution was slowest

[image]

### Details

Tests were divided into two groups: in-place solutions (AI, BI, and CI) and non-in-place solutions (D, E, and F) and was performed for two cases:

- test for an array with 10 elements - you can run it [here](https://jsbench.me/bhk9e06ktc/1)
- test for an array with 1,000,000 elements - you can run it [here](https://jsbench.me/20k9e0au9q/1)

Tested code is presented in the below snippet:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lamik/b14wkntp/)

```js
function AI(arr, i, el) {
  arr.splice(i, 0, el);
  return arr;
}

function BI(arr, i, el) {
  Array.prototype.splice.apply(arr, [i, 0, el]);
  return arr;
}

function CI(arr, i, el) {
  Array.prototype.splice.call(arr, i, 0, el);
  return arr;
}

function D(arr, i, el) {
  return arr.slice(0, i).concat(el, arr.slice(i));
}

function E(arr, i, el) {
  return [...arr.slice(0, i), el, ...arr.slice(i)]
}

function F(arr, i, el) {
  return arr.reduce((s, a, j)=> (j-i ? s.push(a) : s.push(el, a), s), []);
}



// -------------
// TEST
// -------------

let arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];

let log = (n, f) => {
  let a = f([...arr], 3, "NEW");
  console.log(`${n}: [${a}]`);
};

log('AI', AI);
log('BI', BI);
log('CI', CI);
log('D', D);
log('E', E);
log('F', F);
```

```html
This snippet only presents tested code (it not perform tests)
```

Example results for a small array on Google Chrome are below:

[image]

Comment: The answer doesn't address the OP's question.

Comment: @kabirbaidhya actually in this answer you can find many solutions to OP question, but additional value in this answer is performance comparison between them - 
I hope many people will find it useful

Comment: Perhaps, you may want to restructure your answer a bit so that it's intuitive for the users to see the possible solutions first and their performance implications later. It looks primarily focused on performance rn.

Answer (score 40):

For proper functional programming and chaining purposes, an invention of `Array.prototype.insert()` is essential. Actually, the `splice` could have been perfect if it had returned the mutated array instead of a totally meaningless empty array. So here it goes:

```js
Array.prototype.insert = function(i,...rest){
  this.splice(i,0,...rest)
  return this
}

var a = [3,4,8,9];
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(a.insert(2,5,6,7)) + "</pre>");
```

Well, OK, the above with the `Array.prototype.splice()` one mutates the original array and some might complain like "you shouldn't modify what doesn't belong to you" and that might turn out to be right as well. So for the public welfare, I would like to give another `Array.prototype.insert()` which doesn't mutate the original array. Here it goes;

```js
Array.prototype.insert = function(i,...rest){
  return this.slice(0,i).concat(rest,this.slice(i));
}

var a = [3,4,8,9],
    b = a.insert(2,5,6,7);
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
console.log(JSON.stringify(b));
```

Comment: "a totally meaningless empty array" - it only returns an empty array when the second parameter is 0. If it's greater than 0, it returns the items removed from the array. Given that you're adding to a prototype, and `splice` mutates the original array, I don't think "proper functional programming" belongs anywhere in the vicinity of `splice`.

Comment: We are talking about insert here and the second parameter of Array.prototype.splice() has to be zero. And what it returns have no meaning other than "i have not deleted anything" and since we use it for inserting an item we already have that information. If you don't want to mutate the original array then you can do the same with two Array.prototype.slice() and one Array.prototype.concat() operations. It's up to you.

Comment: Your second implementation is the cleanest from this whole page and you have zero votes. Please take mine and keep up the good work. (you should just avoid mutating the prototype but you already know that)

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that the rest parameter is new ECMA 6th  (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters )

Answer (score 33):

I recommend using pure **JavaScript** in this case. Also there isn't any insert method in JavaScript, but we have a method which is a **built-in Array** method which does the job for you. It's called **splice**...

Let's see what's **splice()**...

> The splice() method changes the contents of an array by removing
> existing elements and/or adding new elements.

OK, imagine we have this array below:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

We can remove `3` like this:

```
arr.splice(arr.indexOf(3), 1);
```

It will return 3, but if we check the arr now, we have:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5]
```

So far, so good, but how we can add a new element to array using splice?

Let's put back 3 in the arr...

```
arr.splice(2, 0, 3);
```

Let's see what we have done...

We use **splice** again, but this time for the second argument, we pass **0**, meaning we don't want to delete any item, but at the same time, we add a third argument which is the 3 that will be added at second index...

You should be aware that we can **delete** and **add** at the same time. For example, now we can do:

```
arr.splice(2, 2, 3);
```

Which will delete **two items** at index 2. Then add **3** at index 2 and the result will be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5];
```

This is showing how each item in *splice* work:

> array.splice(start, deleteCount, item1, item2, item3 ...)

Comment: Thanks for explaining in future i suggest using non digit numbers for the array values, for showing an example.  Eg:  arr.splice(2, 0, 3)   vs  arr.splice(2, 0, "C"). Easier for the reader to comprehend which argument maps to the value part and which one maps to the index part. Thank you!

Answer (score 24):

Here are two ways:

```js
const array = [ 'My', 'name', 'Hamza' ];

array.splice(2, 0, 'is');

console.log("Method 1: ", array.join(" "));
```

Or

```js
Array.prototype.insert = function ( index, item ) {
    this.splice( index, 0, item );
};

const array = [ 'My', 'name', 'Hamza' ];
array.insert(2, 'is');

console.log("Method 2 : ", array.join(" "));
```

Answer (score 23):

Append a single element at a specific index:

```
// Append at a specific position (here at index 1)
arrName.splice(1, 0,'newName1');
// 1: index number, 0: number of element to remove, newName1: new element


// Append at a specific position (here at index 3)
arrName[3] = 'newName1';
```

Append multiple elements at a specific index:

```
// Append from index number 1
arrName.splice(1, 0, 'newElemenet1', 'newElemenet2', 'newElemenet3');
// 1: index number from where append start,
// 0: number of element to remove,
//newElemenet1,2,3: new elements
```

Comment: Worth noticing that arrName[3] does not append, it overrides.

Comment: It add the element to the existing array not over ride, Ex: let arrName = ['xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz']; arrName.splice(1, 0,'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'); after print the arrName

Comment: If arrName has more than 3 elements you are overriding the 3rd, not appending. Or am I looking this at the wrong way?

Comment: If we insert an element on the middle, it shift the next element not overide. Please specify your problem, what you need. Take an array(example) and what you need on the output. plz comment me

Comment: I dont have a problem, what I am saying is that this does not append: arrName[3]. You are overriding whatever is in the 4th position.

Comment: @Srikrushna `arrName[3] = 'newName1';` will append if the array has only 3 elements. If there is an element in index 3, this will be replaced. If you want to append at end, it is better to use `arrName.push('newName1');`

Comment: @awe I am agree in your comment, but the question is in specific index, we have to insert the elements. For that question my answer is right

Answer (score 17):

[`Array#splice()`](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/array-splice) is the way to go, unless you really want to avoid mutating the array. Given 2 arrays `arr1` and `arr2`, here's how you would insert the contents of `arr2` into `arr1` after the first element:

```js
const arr1 = ['a', 'd', 'e'];
const arr2 = ['b', 'c'];

arr1.splice(1, 0, ...arr2); // arr1 now contains ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

console.log(arr1)
```

If you are concerned about mutating the array (for example, if using Immutable.js), you can instead use [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), not to be confused with `splice()` with a `'p'`.

```
const arr3 = [...arr1.slice(0, 1), ...arr2, ...arr1.slice(1)];
```

Answer (score 15):

Another possible solution, with usage of `Array.reduce`.

```js
const arr = ["apple", "orange", "raspberry"];
const arr2 = [1, 2, 4];

const insert = (arr, item, index) =>
  arr.reduce(function(s, a, i) {
    i === index ? s.push(item, a) : s.push(a);
    return s;
  }, []);

console.log(insert(arr, "banana", 1));
console.log(insert(arr2, 3, 2))
```

Answer (score 10):

Even though this has been answered already, I'm adding this note for an alternative approach.

I wanted to place a **known number** of items into an array, into specific positions, as they come off of an "associative array" (i.e. an object) which by definition is not guaranteed to be in a sorted order. I wanted the resulting array to be an array of objects, but the objects to be in a specific order in the array since an array guarantees their order. So I did this.

First the source object, a [JSONB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654170/explanation-of-jsonb-introduced-by-postgresql) string retrieved from PostgreSQL. I wanted to have it sorted by the "order" property in each child object.

```
var jsonb_str = '{"one": {"abbr": "", "order": 3}, "two": {"abbr": "", "order": 4}, "three": {"abbr": "", "order": 5}, "initialize": {"abbr": "init", "order": 1}, "start": {"abbr": "", "order": 2}}';

var jsonb_obj = JSON.parse(jsonb_str);
```

Since the number of nodes in the object is known, I first create an array with the specified length:

```
var obj_length = Object.keys(jsonb_obj).length;
var sorted_array = new Array(obj_length);
```

And then iterate the object, placing the newly created temporary objects into the desired locations in the array without really any "sorting" taking place.

```
for (var key of Object.keys(jsonb_obj)) {
  var tobj = {};
  tobj[key] = jsonb_obj[key].abbr;

  var position = jsonb_obj[key].order - 1;
  sorted_array[position] = tobj;
}

console.dir(sorted_array);
```

Answer (score 10):

#### Immutable insertion

Using the [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method is surely the best answer if you need to insert into an array in-place.

However, if you are looking for an immutable function that returns a new updated array instead of mutating the original array on insert, you can use the following function.

```js
function insert(array, index) {
  const items = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);

  return [].concat(array.slice(0, index), items, array.slice(index));
}

const list = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

const list1 = insert(list, 0, 'zero'); // Insert single item
const list2 = insert(list, 3, 'four', 'five', 'six'); // Insert multiple

console.log('Original list: ', list);
console.log('Inserted list1: ', list1);
console.log('Inserted list2: ', list2);
```

**Note:** This is a pre-[ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) way of doing it, so it works for both older and newer browsers.

If you're using ES6 then you can try out [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) too; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/how-to-insert-an-item-into-an-array-at-a-specific-index-javascript/586189#answer-38181008).

Answer (score 8):

Anyone who's still having issues with this one and have tried all the options in previous answers and never got it. I'm sharing my solution, and this is to take into consideration that you don't want to explicitly state the properties of your object vs the array.

```
function isIdentical(left, right){
    return JSON.stringify(left) === JSON.stringify(right);
}

function contains(array, obj){
    let count = 0;
    array.map((cur) => {
        if(this.isIdentical(cur, obj)) 
            count++;
    });
    return count > 0;
}
```

This is a combination of iterating the reference array and comparing it to the object you wanted to check, converting both of them into a string, and then iterating if it matched. Then you can just count. This can be improved, but this is where I settled.

Answer (score 8):

Taking profit of the *reduce* method as follows:

```
function insert(arr, val, index) {
    return index >= arr.length
        ? arr.concat(val)
        : arr.reduce((prev, x, i) => prev.concat(i === index ? [val, x] : x), []);
}
```

So in this way we can return a new array (will be a cool functional way - more much better than using *push* or *splice*) with the element inserted at index, and if the index is greater than the length of the array it will be inserted at the end.

Answer (score 7):

I tried this and it is working fine!

```
var initialArr = ["India","China","Japan","USA"];
initialArr.splice(index, 0, item);
```

Index is the position where you want to insert or delete the element.

0, i.e., the second parameter, defines the number of elements from the index to be removed.
`item` contains the new entries which you want to make in the array. It can be one or more than one.

```
initialArr.splice(2, 0, "Nigeria");
initialArr.splice(2, 0, "Australia","UK");
```

Comment: simply copy pasted the answer above. this is not adding any value to the question. either you add a new answer or comment on existing. please try to contribute something new. we dont want to spoil this community

Answer (score 6):

I have to agree with Redu's answer because splice() definitely has a bit of a confusing interface. And the response given by cdbajorin that "it only returns an empty array when the second parameter is 0. If it's greater than 0, it returns the items removed from the array" is, while accurate, proving the point.

The function's intent is to splice or as said earlier by Jakob Keller, "to join or connect, also to change.

You have an established array that you are now changing which would involve adding or removing elements...." Given that, the return value of the elements, if any, that were removed is awkward at best. And I 100% agree that this method could have been better suited to chaining if it had returned what seems natural, a new array with the spliced elements added. Then you could do things like ["19", "17"].splice(1,0,"18").join("...") or whatever you like with the returned array.

The fact that it returns what was removed is just kind of nonsense IMHO. If the intention of the method was to "cut out a set of elements" and that was its only intent, maybe. It seems like if I don't know what I'm cutting out already though, I probably have little reason to cut those elements out, doesn't it?

It would be better if it behaved like concat(), map(), reduce(), slice(), etc. where a new array is made from the existing array rather than mutating the existing array. Those are all chainable, and that *is* a significant issue. It's rather common to chain array manipulation.

It seems like the language needs to go one or the other direction and try to stick to it as much as possible. JavaScript being functional and less declarative, it just seems like a strange deviation from the norm.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with array.splice:

```
/**
 * @param arr:  Array
 * @param item:  item to insert
 * @param index: index at which to insert 
 * @returns array with the inserted element
 */
export function _arrayInsertAt<T>(arr: T[], item: T, index: number) {
    return  arr.splice(index, 0, item);; 
}
```

[Doc of array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a working function that I use in one of my applications.

This checks if an item exists:

```
let ifExist = (item, strings = [ '' ], position = 0) => {
     // Output into an array with an empty string. Important just in case their isn't any item.
    let output = [ '' ];
    // Check to see if the item that will be positioned exist.
    if (item) {
        // Output should be equal to an array of strings.
        output = strings;
       // Use splice() in order to break the array.
       // Use positional parameters to state where to put the item
       // and 0 is to not replace an index. Item is the actual item we are placing at the prescribed position.
        output.splice(position, 0, item);
    }
    // Empty string is so we do not concatenate with comma or anything else.
    return output.join("");
};
```

And then I call it below.

```
ifExist("friends", [ ' ( ', ' )' ], 1)}  // Output: ( friends )
ifExist("friends", [ ' - '], 1)}  // Output:  - friends
ifExist("friends", [ ':'], 0)}  // Output:   friends:
```

Comment: Can you explain your solution please ?

Answer (score 5):

I like a little safety and I use this:

```js
Array.prototype.Insert = function (item, before) {
  if (!item) return;
  if (before == null || before < 0 || before > this.length - 1) {
    this.push(item);
    return;
  }
  this.splice(before, 0, item);
}


var t = ["a", "b"]

t.Insert("v", 1)

console.log(t)
```

Comment: You said you like safety, then suggest to modify basic prototype! logic? no

Comment: yep .. it is m y definition of safety .. lol

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the original array untouched but return a new array with the element inserted into a particular index you can use the new [`.toSpliced()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSpliced) method:

This avoids mutating the array [in place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm):

```js
//                0    1    2
const letters = ["A", "B", "D"];
const insertIndex = 2; // position in the array to insert 
const correctLetters = letters.toSpliced(insertIndex, 0, "C"); // 0 means don't delete any items, just insert. "C" is the item you want to insert.
console.log(correctLetters); // ["A", "B", "C", "D"] (new array contains new char)
console.log(letters); // ["A", "B", "D"] (unmodified)
```

If you need to insert multiple items into the array, just like its sibling [`.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), you can use `.toSpliced()` with multiple arguments:

```
.toSpliced(insertIndex, 0, "C", "D", "E");
```

The above, for example, will insert `"C"`, `"D"`, and `"E"` at `insertIndex` into the array without modifying it, returning a new array instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
//Suppose we have an array  
let myArray = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];  

// Index where we want to insert the item  
let indexToInsert = 3;  

// Item we want to insert  
let itemToInsert = 174;  

// Now we Using splice() method to insert the item at the specified index  
myArray.splice(indexToInsert, 0, itemToInsert);  

// output with new value    
console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the modern (Typescript functional) way:

```
export const insertItemInList = <T>(
  arr: T[],
  index: number,
  newItem: T
): T[] => [...arr.slice(0, index), newItem, ...arr.slice(index)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I do it like so:

```
const insert = (what, where, index) => 
  ([...where.slice(0, index), what , ...where.slice(index, where.length)]);
```

```js
const insert = (what, where, index) =>
  ([...where.slice(0, index), what , ...where.slice(index, where.length)]);
  
const list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const newList = insert('a', list, 2);

console.log(newList.indexOf('a') === 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple function that supports inserting multiple values at the same time:

```
function add_items_to_array_at_position(array, index, new_items)
{
    return [...array.slice(0, index), ...new_items, ...array.slice(index)];
}
```

Usage example:

```
let old_array = [1,2,5];

let new_array = add_items_to_array_at_position(old_array, 2, [3,4]);

console.log(new_array);

//Output: [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: This is similar to many of the existing answers but with a concise combination of function / spread operator / multiple items / example / output that hasn't been posted yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
var array= [10,20,30,40]

var i;

var pos=2; //pos=index + 1
/*pos is position which we want to insert at which is index + 1.position two in an array is index 1.*/

var value=5 
//value to insert

//Initialize from last array element

for(i=array.length-1;i>=pos-1;i--){

array[i+1]=array[i]

}

array[pos-1]=value

console.log(array)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Multi purpose for `ARRAY` and `ARRAY OF OBJECT` reusable approach

```js
let arr = [0,1,2];
let obj = [{ name: "abc"},{ name: "xyz"},{ name: "ijk"} ];

const addArrayItemAtIndex = ( array, index, newItem ) => {
    return [...array.slice(0, index), newItem, ...array.slice(index)];
}

// For Array
console.log( addArrayItemAtIndex(arr, 2,  159 ) );

// For Array of Objects
console.log( addArrayItemAtIndex(obj, 0, { name: "AMOOS"} ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of answers but nobody mentions that `splice` can't insert past the last element of the array.

```js
const insertIntoArray = (array, index, ...values) => {
  while (index > array.length) {
    array.push(undefined);
  }
  array.splice(index, 0, ...values);
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a particular reason for using `while` rather than `if`? And isn't it supposed to `return` as soon as the `push`ing is done?

Answer (score 0):

```
const x = [3, 2, 6, 6, 2]

function addToIndex(arr, index, val){
  let prevArr = arr.slice(0, index)
  let nextArr = arr.slice(index)
  return [...prevArr, val, ...nextArr]
}

console.log(addToIndex(x, 2, 'hello'))
```

Comment: Looks a lot like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38181008/

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but here is a contribution to the effort, which allows for insertion of provided array into original array at a specific position, maintaining the size of the original array regardless of overflow in any direction. I didn't find this edge case in previous comments, so here we go.

```
Array.prototype.insertAt = function(pos, arr) {

    // Inserts array <arr> at position <pos>

    // pos can be negative in which case the inserted array is trimmed.
    // Overflowing array elements will be trimmed so that the length of original array will always be retained.

    if(pos<0) {
        if(Math.abs(pos) > arr.length) {
            return this
        } else {
            var del1 = arr.length - (arr.length + pos);
            var partial = arr.slice(Math.abs(arr.length - (arr.length + pos)), arr.length);
            this.splice(0, arr.length + pos);
            this.unshift.apply(this, partial);
        }
    } else {
        if(pos > this.length) {
            return this;
        }
        var insertIndex = pos;
        var insertLength = Math.min((this.length - insertIndex), arr.length);
        var args = [insertIndex, insertLength].concat(arr.slice(0, insertLength));
        Array.prototype.splice.apply(this, args);
    }
}
```

```js
Array.prototype.insertAt = function(pos, arr) {

    // Inserts array <arr> at position <pos>

    // pos can be negative in which case the arr end is trimmed.
    // Overflowing array elements will be trimmed so that the length of original array will always be retained.

    if(pos<0) {
        if(Math.abs(pos) > arr.length) {
            return this
        } else {
            var del1 = arr.length - (arr.length + pos);
            var partial = arr.slice(Math.abs(arr.length - (arr.length + pos)), arr.length);
            this.splice(0, arr.length + pos);
            this.unshift.apply(this, partial);
        }
    } else {
        if(pos > this.length) {
            return this;
        }
        var insertIndex = pos;
        var insertLength = Math.min((this.length - insertIndex), arr.length);
        var args = [insertIndex, insertLength].concat(arr.slice(0, insertLength));
        Array.prototype.splice.apply(this, args);
    }
}
    var b = [1,2,3,4,5];
    var a = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    
    var numIterations = a.length + b.length;

    for(var j= -b.length; j < numIterations; j++) {

        var c = a.slice();

        c.insertAt(j, b);

        console.log("Position: " + j + ", result: [" + c.toString() + "]");
    }
```