# Difference between splice and insert

Tags: c++, list, stl

Recently I came across functions of list container in STL, i saw

```
list::splice and list::insert
```

For me it seems that both does the same job of inserting, I can't specifically find a difference, also i can't find the difference anywhere.
So what is specifically the difference, and is there anything special to splice?

Comment: Take a look at [Javascript - insert an array inside another array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032550/javascript-insert-an-array-inside-another-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splice will move items from the source to the destination. Insert will copy them from the source to the destination. Splice is faster, but will modify the source list, whereas insert takes longer but leaves the original list intact.

Answer (score 3):

`splice` will concatenate two lists in `O(1)` time, without any copying of data. `insert` involves copying data, and if you want to concatenate two lists using `insert`, it will take `O(N)` time, where N is the number of elements in the list you want to append.

Also, splice will modify (actually, empty), the appended list.

Comment: You didn't mention anything about modifying the original list.

Comment: That used to be true, but since idiots forced the standard to maintain constant-time `size()` for lists, splice is O(n).

Comment: @ZanLynx: `this->size += other.size()`, what's the problem? How does a requirement for constant-time size make it impossible to splice in constant time?

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan splicing a subset of a list requires iterating through it to see how much to alter the source & destination lists sizes by