# How can I copy elements from one array to another of a different type given a particular index in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
var arrayA = [ 0, 0, 0 ];
var arrayB = new Uint8Array( 2 );
arrayB[0] = 1;
arrayB[1] = 2;
```

I would like to copy the values from arrayB to a particular index in arrayA.

For example:

```
arrayB.copyTo( arrayA, 1 );
```

arrayA would now become:

```
[0, 1, 2, 0, 0];
```

Is there a way of doing this in vanilla javascript without using an iterator?

Comment: There is a [good solution here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348178/a-better-way-to-splice-an-array-into-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: `Array.prototype.splice.apply( arrayA, [1, 0, arrayB] );` adds the array to the index and not the values of the array.

Comment: Thanks for checking out the link, You need: `Array.prototype.splice.apply(array, [index, 0].concat(arrayToInsert));`

Answer (score 0):

This is called "splicing". I'm not sure why you're using the `Uint8Array` constructor, but if you are working with two normal arrays, this is how I would do it:

```js
var arrayA = [0,0,0];
var arrayB = [1, 2];

var spliceArrays = function(arr1, arr2, index) {
  var arrPart1 = arr1.slice(0, index);
  var arrPart2 = arr1.slice(index);
  return (arrPart1.concat(arr2)).concat(arrPart2);
};

var spliced = spliceArrays(arrayA, arrayB, 1);

console.log(spliced);
```