# How to add a new value to the end of an numerical array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In PHP I can do like:

```
$arrayname[] = 'value';
```

Then the value will be put in the last numerical key eg. 4 if the 3 keys already exists.

In JavaScript I can’t do the same with:

```
arrayname[] = 'value';
```

How do you do it in JavaScript?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `push` method.

For instance *(using Firebug to test quickly)* :

First, declare an array that contains a couple of items :

```
>>> var a = [10, 20, 30, 'glop'];
```

The array contains :

```
>>> a
[10, 20, 30, "glop"]
```

And now, `push` a new value to its end :

```
>>> a.push('test');
5
```

The array now contains :

```
>>> a
[10, 20, 30, "glop", "test"]
```

Comment: To add multiple elements at the same time or to add an element somewhere other than the end check out the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12189963/984780

Comment: Just to help other rookies who come along, do NOT try `a = a.push('test');` for 10 mins. :)

Answer (score 11):

You can use

```
arrayName.push('yourValue');
```

OR

`arrayName[arrayName.length] = 'yourvalue';`

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can use array push method

```
arrayname.push('value');
```