# How to insert something in the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have for example this array-variable:

```
var arr=[  
[1,2,3]  
[4,5,6]  
]
```

How can I insert something in that array, for example like this:

```
arr=[  
[1,2,3]  
[4,5,6]   
[7,8,9]  
]
```

I tried `arr=[arr,[7,8,9]]` but then the `[]` are building up.

How to do this?

Comment: How about reading [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object)?

Comment: Duplicate. [How to add a new value to the end of an numerical array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961488/how-to-add-a-new-value-to-the-end-of-an-numerical-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
arr.push([7,8,9]);
```

That should do the trick.
If you want to insert:

```
arr.splice(offset,0,thing_to_insert);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```
arr.push([7,8,9]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
arr.push([7,8,9]);
```

`push()` is a standard array method

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var arr=[  
[1,2,3]  
[4,5,6]  
] ;
arr.push([7,8,9]);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) adds elements to the end of an array.

```
var arr=[  
    [1,2,3]  
    [4,5,6]  
    ];

arr.push([7,8,9]);
```

[`Array.prototype.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) lets you add elements to the array at any index you desire:

```
var arr=[  
    [1,2,3]  
    [4,5,6]  
    ];

arr.splice(arr.length, 0, [7,8,9]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use push?

I'm not sure if this would work:

`arr.push([7,8,9]);`

but I'm sure this would work:

```
arr.push(7);
arr.push(8);
arr.push(9);
```

Comment: `arr` after your last code would look like this: `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],7,8,9]` ... which is not correct.