# Javascript: What's a better way to splice arrays together than what I'm using now?

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-splice

```
var newlist = list.slice( 0, pos ).concat( tasks ).concat( list.slice( pos ) );
```

This makes me shudder just looking at it.

Comment: it doesn't look that bad to me. It might be a little faster to just scoot the tail of the array out and drop in the new element, however. If you have to do this a *lot* you might want to think about a better data structure anyway.

Comment: You mean a tree of some kind?  What would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't want to modify the original array, you can shorten yours a little like this:

```
var newlist = ​list.slice(0,pos).concat(tasks,list.slice(pos));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RgYPw/

Comment: It looks like you are trying to insert an array in the middle of another array. You can use the function `insertArrayAt()` in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12189963/984780. You would use it like this `insertArrayAt(list, pos, tasks)`. This alters `list` if you want a new list use `slice(0)` to clone the list first. Like so:  `var newlist = insertArrayAt(list.slice(0), pos, tasks)`

Answer (score 2):

There is a [splice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) method for Array.

Comment: But that appears to need each parameter listed out.  How do I unfurl another array to be that function's extended parameters, then?  Or DOES it accept an array parameter to splice together (as opposed to splicing the passed array as only a single item in the new array)?

Comment: Yikes, that is ugly.  You could use the `apply` method of the `splice` function and build the parameter array from the array you want to splice in, but that's exceptionally hideous.  I'm thinking you're better off with your version.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is as good as any- 
you'd have to splice each member of your second array individually.

```
var list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], tasks= ['a','b','c'], pos=3;


while(tasks.length ) list.splice(pos,0,tasks.pop());
```

alert(list.join('\n'))

```
/*  returned value:
1
2
3
a
b
c
4
5
6
7
8
9
*/
```