# How to add/insert an item into an ObservableArray at a certain position with Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

All the knockout examples I have found seem to add a new item to the end of an ObservableArray using something like:

```
viewModel.SomeItems.push(someNewItem);
```

This of course places the item at the end of the array.

**How to I add an item to the ObservableArray at a certain position?**

eg. something like:

```
viewModel.SomeItems.push(someNewItem, indexToInsertItAt);
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You should be able to use the native JavaScript `splice` method -

```
viewModel.SomeItems.splice(2,0,someNewItem);
```

Docs here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Example here (not Knockout specific) - [How to insert an item into an array at a specific index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/javascript-insert-item-into-array-at-a-specific-index)

From the Knockout docs -

> For functions that modify the contents of the array, such as push and
>   splice, KO’s methods automatically trigger the dependency tracking
>   mechanism so that all registered listeners are notified of the change,
>   and your UI is automatically updated.

Comment: Thanks. Splice worked. For knockout users, ko.utils.arrayIndexOf is also useful if you want to find the index to insert your new item based on an existing item.

Comment: This won't work with sparse arrays, at least it didn't for me in chrome.  See my answer below

Answer (score 24):

For knockout use

```
viewModel.SomeItems.unshift(someNewItem);
```

See also: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html

Comment: This insert the item at the beginning of the array so doesn't help if you want to insert an item seomwhere in the middle.

Comment: I somehow missed the part about inserting it anywhere in the array. Yes this only works if you want to insert into the beginning. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 12):

I made this extension function which worked nicely for me.  Splice wasn't working for me if I was adding to the end of a sparse array.

```
ko.observableArray.fn.setAt = function(index, value) {
    this.valueWillMutate();
    this()[index] = value;
    this.valueHasMutated();
}
```

This even works with:

```
var a = ko.observableArray(['a', 'b', 'c']);
a.setAt(42, 'the answer');
```

Comment: And if you want to do insertAt rather than setAt, just switch `this()[index] = value;` to `this.splice(index, 0, value);`.  Thanks Adam!