# how do i insert element in knockout array at specific index

Tags: knockout.js, ko.observablearray

how do i insert element in knockout array at specific index

I understand we have to use slice and push, but what is the best way and how to insert new element at specific position in observable array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add/insert an item into an ObservableArray at a certain position with Knockout.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317907/how-to-add-insert-an-item-into-an-observablearray-at-a-certain-position-with-kno)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `splice`. The [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) aren't real clear on this (I had to double check it myself), but you can use this just like the regular javascript [.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to insert elements as well as remove them. For example:

```
var vm = {
    array : ko.observableArray(["foo","bar"])
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);

function Add() {
    vm.array.splice(1,0,"ra");    // at index 1 - remove 0 elements and add "ra"
}

Add();   // "ra" gets inserted between "foo" and "bar"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aL4D6/

Comment: Matt, just because I'm curious, why not define the `add` function as part of your view model?  It has a dependency on vm existing in the global namespace right now.  Instead you could insert the function as an additional property when defining `vm` as in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLLnF/). Then, you can even interact with the function through binding as well as in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLLnF/1/)(great answer btw, I +1'd you)

Comment: @KyleMit: Because I was banging something together quickly to demonstrate the principle. Without a doubt I would put it in the VM in practice.

Comment: Yeah, fair enough.  I'm new to knockout, so I didn't know if there was something else in play.  The question left a lot of imagination to the implementation.

Comment: Thanks Matt, This code works but doesn't do auto ui refresh, I had to write valueWillMutate() & valueHasMutated() for auto UI refresh to work, do you have idea on what they do? Thanks again.

Comment: @ritzy: It works fine in my fiddle. You must have something else going on. If you ask another question and include you code (preferably in a fiddle), somebody can probably help you.

Answer (score 2):

I you can do it normally with [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) (no reasons for slice and push, because splice can actually do this). Just put you starting position and then 0 to specify that you actually do not want to remove an item, and only add.

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.list = ko.observableArray([1, 2, 3, 5]);
};
vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

So if you then do something like

```
vm.list.splice(3,0, 'new element');
```

it will insert it at specific location in the array. Surely you can put this code inside of the model and bind it to some event.

Comment: How do you get access to the bound ViewModel to splice it - the copy and paste of the code seems to not work in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3vCdD/

Comment: @KyleMit sorry for this. Updated fiddle is here (answer updated as well): http://jsfiddle.net/3vCdD/1/