# Knokout new on item on top of list

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

I have

```
 KnockoutObservableArray<string>
```

and I show this list by

```
<div data-bind="template: { foreach: City, afterAdd: showElement, beforeRemove: hideElement }">.
```

If I added a new city to this list it shows on end of list, but I need show new city as first item. How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add/insert an item into an ObservableArray at a certain position with Knockout.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317907/how-to-add-insert-an-item-into-an-observablearray-at-a-certain-position-with-kno)

Comment: Working version based on answer in duplicate: http://jsfiddle.net/bxfXd/4506/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to insert into the collection use

```
viewModel.City.unshift("new City");
```