# Updating knockout observableArray with AJAX callback produces randomly sorted results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

Here is some code that replicates the issue

```
places = ["London","Paris","Brussels"];
placeWikis = ko.observableArray([]);

var viewModel = function(){

for (i in places) {
    function wikiInit(callback){
        this.wikiMarkup = "";

        var wikiTitle = places[i].replace(" ", "_");
        var wikiURL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles="+places[i];

        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            dataType:"jsonp",
            async: false,
            url: wikiURL,

            success: function(result){
                callback(result.query.pages[Object.keys(result.query.pages)[0]].extract);
            },
            error: function(){

            }
        });
    };

    wikiInit(function (wikiString) {
        var wikiMarkup = "<h4>Wikipedia:</h4>" + "<p>" + wikiString + "</p>";

        placeWikis.push(wikiMarkup);

        console.log(placeWikis());
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(), view);
```

The issue is every time this code runs and returns data from the source, Wikipedia in this case, the results for placesWikis() are ordered randomly. I am adding the API results separately on a different `<div>`, so I need the indexes for the results to be the same as the indexes for their respective entries in places[]

Comment: I think you might have a well-disguised duplicate of this question: [Elements order in a “for (… in …)” loop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/280861/419956)? If order is important, you should sort yourself. (Note that, if you need a *stable* sort you should have an explicit tiebreaker too, as array sorting in Javascript isn't guaranteed to be a stable sort - AFAIK.)

Comment: So I guess that means there is no easy solution. Great.

Comment: Why not? If you change from `for..in` to a regular `for` loop things should work out, right?

Comment: Hmm, I was wrong. That *might* be an issue, though probably not the one you're seeing. Instead, it's the fact that the Ajax success handlers return in non-deterministic order as they're handled asycnhronously. I've posted an answer with some two possible solutions. (In addition, I suggest replacing `for..in` with `for` anyways.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues with order:

- [`for.in`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/280861/419956) does not guarantee order;
- you fill the `observableArray` asynchronously in callbacks, but there is no guarantee that they will arrive in order you fire them off!

The latter is probably the most prominent issue. You currently `push` results into your observable array, but you do so in the order by which the browser returns results.

Here's a slightly more minimal repro of your problem, with the differences callback timings exagerated:

```js
// Mock Ajax stuff:
var $ = {
  ajax: function(options) {
    // Simulate unknown return moment with setTimeout:
    setTimeout(function() {
      options.success(options.url + " is a great city...");
    }, Math.random() * 1500 + 50);
  }
}

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
  
  var places = ["london", "brussels", "paris"];
  
  function wikiInit(place, callback) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/" + place,
      success: function(result) {
        callback(result);
      }
    });
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
    wikiInit(places[i], function(wikiString) {
      self.items.push(wikiString);
      console.log(self.items());
    });
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
  <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, every time your run this you have a *chance* the results are out of order.

**Option 1** is to [splice new items into the array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7318044/419956) in the position you want them in (instead of using `push`). This is IMO a bit convoluted approach, and I'll leave the code to do so to the reader.

**Option 2**, and a probably easier approach is to prepare the array beforehand, and on the callbacks fill the array. E.g. like this:

```js
// Mock Ajax stuff:
var $ = {
  ajax: function(options) {
    // Simulate unknown return moment with setTimeout:
    setTimeout(function() {
      options.success(options.url + " is a great city...");
    }, Math.random() * 1500 + 50);
  }
}

function Place(data) {
  this.place = data.place;
  this.wikistuff = ko.observable("");
}

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
  
  var places = ["london", "brussels", "paris"];
  
  function wikiInit(place, callback) {
    var placeVm = new Place({ place: place });
    self.items.push(placeVm);
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/" + place,
      success: function(result) {
        callback(result, placeVm);
      }
    });
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
    wikiInit(places[i], function(wikiString, placeVm) {
      placeVm.wikistuff(wikiString);
    });
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
  <li data-bind="text: wikistuff"></li>
</ul>
```

This result is *always* in order of the original array.

It currently always shows the bullets, even before the callback completed. I only did so to demonstrate how the solution works, but you could easily do this...

```html
<li data-bind="text: wikistuff, visible: !!wikistuff()"></li>
```

...if needed.