# javascript array splice without index

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-splice

I was wondering about this piece of code:

```
var numbers, _ref;
numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

[].splice.apply(numbers, [3, 4].concat(_ref = [-3, -4, -5, -6])), _ref;
alert(numbers);
```

From [here](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3anumbers%20%3D%20%5B0%2C%201%2C%202%2C%203%2C%204%2C%205%2C%206%2C%207%2C%208%2C%209%5D%0A%0Anumbers%5B3..6%5D%20%3D%20%5B-3%2C%20-4%2C%20-5%2C%20-6%5D%0A%0Aalert%20numbers), the result is `[0, 1, 2, -3, -4, -5, -6, 7, 8, 9]`
and can anyone explain me about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*function*.apply(context, argsArray) calls *function* in the given context, passing argsArray as the arguments for *function*.

In this case, *function* is `[].splice`, which takes the following parameters, in this this order:

1. *index* - at which to start changing the array
2. *howMany* - elements to remove, starting at *index*
3. *element1,...,elementN* - elements to insert into the array at *index*

`[3,4].concat(_ref = [-3, -4, -5, -6])` evaluates to an array by concatenating the two arrays together, giving `[3, 4, -3, -4, -5, -6]`. This is the argsArray passed to `.apply()`, so that:

1. *index* == 3 (start at index 3)
2. *howMany* == 4 (remove 4 elements)
3. *element1,...,elementN* == -3, -4, -5, -6 (the elements to insert at index 3, after removal)

Thus `.apply()` is causing the `.splice()` function to run in the context of the `numbers` array, removing elements at indices 3, 4, 5 and 6, and then inserting the elements -3, -4, -5 and -6 between "2" and "7" in the original array.

Edit: See RobG's answer for a summary of what the original code is equivalent to (rather than an explanation of its parts).

Comment: Whoever gave that -1, care to explain why?

Comment: If what you are looking for is an easy to use function that does this check out `insertArrayAt()` in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12189963/984780

Answer (score 1):

Your code resolves to the following variable declarations:

```
var numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var _ref = [-3, -4, -5, -6];
```

And these expressions:

```
numbers.splice(3, 4, -3, -4, -5, -6);
_ref;
alert(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

`[3, 4].concat(_ref = [-3, -4, -5, -6])` evals to `[3, 4, -3, -4, -5, -6]` and `[].splice.apply(numbers, [3, 4, -3, -4, -5, -6]))` to `numbers.splice(3, 4, -3, -4, -5, -6)` causing 4 elements stating from index 3 to be removed and the elements "-3, -4, -5, -6" to be inserted at the index 3. See [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).