# How to push to an array in a particular position?

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript

I'm trying to efficiently write a statement that pushes to position 1 of an array, and pushes whatever is in that position, or after it back a spot.

```
array = [4,5,9,6,2,5]

#push 0 to position 1

array = [4,0,5,9,6,2,5]

#push 123 to position 1

array = [4,123,0,5,9,6,2,5]
```

What is the best way to write this? (javascript or coffeescript acceptable)

Thanks!

Comment: you can use this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/javascript-insert-item-into-array-at-a-specific-index

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Comment: @Anand: Please don't feed w3fools.com any more hits, there are much [better](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) references [available](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.12).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert an item into an array at a specific index?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/how-to-insert-an-item-into-an-array-at-a-specific-index)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
array = [4,5,9,6,2,5]

#push 0 to position 1
array.splice(1,0,0)

array = [4,0,5,9,6,2,5]

#push 123 to position 1
array.splice(1,0,123)

array = [4,123,0,5,9,6,2,5]
```

Comment: **Note:** splice returns an array of the _removed_ elements. In these examples, no elements are removed so `console.log(array.splice(1,0,123))` will return `[]`. Should have RTFM

Comment: [The manual](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) also says (as [Vlada](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29098872/4575793) and [user12838586 pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60868093/4575793)) `splice(position, numberOfItemsToRemove, item)`, especially explaining the second parameter.

Answer (score 4):

### The `splice()` function is the only native array function that lets you add elements to the specific place of an array

**I will get a one array that you entered in your question to describe**

```
splice(position, numberOfItemsToRemove, item)
```

- `position` = What is the position that you want to add new item
- `numberOfItemsToRemove` = This indicate how many number of items will deleted. That's
  mean delete will start according to the position that new item add.

> **Ex** = if you want to add 1 position to 123 result will be like this ([4,123,0,5,9,6,2,5])
> but if you give `numberOfItemsToRemove` to 1 it will remove first element after the
> 123 if you give 2 then its delete two element after 123.

- `item` = the new item that you add

```js
function my_func(){
        var suits = [4,0,5,9,6,2,5]
        
        suits.splice(1 , 0 , 123);

        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = suits;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">4,0,5,9,6,2,5</p>
<button id="btn01" onclick="my_func()">Splice Array</button>
```

Comment: Additional info: [you can find the manual here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just do:

```
myArray[idx] = foo;
```

You will need to have an array with the appropriate size, but I'm not sure what the behavior for splice on a list that doesn't have the requested index is either.

Comment: Ah, I've just realized splice works really well if you want to preserve the other elements in the array. duh.

Comment: Yes, @Frank - this method overwrites the element at `idx`, so not an answer here.