# Insert a row in array after the row that matches a name in the array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript array and I need to detect the name in the javascript and then insert immediately after that item in the array. Prefer jQuery and javascript for solution.

```
var arrayExample = 
[{"name":"Test1","id":[1]},
{"name":"Test2","id":[2]},
{"name":"Test3","id":[3]},
{"name":"Test4","id":[4]},
{"name":"Test5","id":[5]}];
```

I want to detect "Test3" and then insert this new array: {"name":"Test3.0001", "id":[3,6]}.

Using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/insert-item-into-array-at-a-specific-index/586189#586189) but would like to add a function that detects the name and automatically splieces in or pushes in the new array using jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

It would be simplest to just iterate through the array and then insert the item when you find the name you're looking for. Something like this ought to do it:

```
function insertAtPoint(arr, item, searchTerm) {
    for(var i = 0, len = arr.length; i<len; i++) {
        if(arr[i].name === searchTerm) {
            arr.splice(i, 0, item);
            return; // we've already found what we're looking for, there's no need to iterate the rest of the array
        }
    }
}
```

You'd then call it like this:

```
insertAtPoint(arrayExample, {name: "Test3.0001", id: [3, 6]}, "Test3"); // I've fudged this object because your example was invalid JS
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
function insertItem(obj,searchTerm){
    $.each(arrayExample,function(i,item){
      if(item.name == searchTerm){
           arrayExample.splice(i+1,0,obj); 
          return false;
      }
    });
}

insertItem({"name":"Test3.0001","id":[3,6]},"Test3");
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BJqN9/3/)

Answer (score 1):

No need for splicing you can modify the object by reference
Try this:

`var modifyId = function(arr, idArr, term) {
    arr.forEach(function(item){
        if(item.name == term) {
            item.id = idArr;
        }
    })
}`

And you can call the function like this:
    `modifyId(arrayExample, [2,4,5], 'Test1')`

Comment: I don't want to replace the contents of an array, I want to insert a new array after the detected string/array row.