# why is index increment value not being reflected in splice in for loop

Tags: variables, loops, for-loop, increment, splice

My results for below code are:

```
--> ZZZ,Banana,Orange,Apple,Mango
--> ZZZ,ZZZ,Banana,Orange,Apple,Mango
--> ZZZ,ZZZ,ZZZ,Banana,Orange,Apple,Mango
--> ZZZ,ZZZ,ZZZ,ZZZ,Banana,Orange,Apple,Mango
--> ZZZ,ZZZ,ZZZ,ZZZ,ZZZ,Banana,Orange,Apple,Mango
```

I want the splice item index to increment along with the loop,
but i in splice is always equal to 0 , please help?

```
  var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
  var proto = fruits
  var i = 0
  a = []
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
  proto.splice(i,0,"ZZZ")

  debug(proto);
  }
```

Comment: So I see that I can use proto.splice(i++,0,"ZZZ") , in order to increment, but now dealing with the issue of assigning the result of proto.splice(i++,0,"ZZZ") to a variable

Comment: just used 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/insert-item-into-array-at-a-specific-index][1]

much better than splice for this


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/insert-item-into-array-at-a-specific-index