# How can I push a null value into the start of an array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code that fetches data and puts it into an array:

```
    this.$httpGetTest(this.test.testId)
        .success(function (data: ITestQuestion[]) {
            self.test.qs = data; 
        });
```

It works and populates the array starting with self.test.qs[0].

However many times my code references this array (which contains a list of questions 1...x)

I must always remember to subract 1 from the question number and so my code does not look clear. Is there a way that I could place an entry ahead of all the others in the array so that:

```
self.test.qs[0] is null
self.test.qs[1] references the first real data for question number 1.
```

Ideally I would like to do this by putting something after the `self.test.qs =` and before `data`.

Comment: Splice the null value into the array before you assign it to `self.test.qs`. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/insert-item-into-array-at-a-specific-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push values at start of array via [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)

```
self.test.qs.unshift(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), It works like:

> The splice() method changes the content of an array, adding new elements while removing old elements.

so try:

```
self.test.qs.splice(0, 0, null);
```

Here mid argument 0 is to set no elements to remove from array so it will insert null at zero and move all other elements.

Here is demo:

```js
var arr = [];
arr[0] = "Hello";
arr[1] = "Friend";

alert(arr.join());
arr.splice(1,0,"my");
alert(arr.join());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start off with an array with a null value in it, then concat the questions array to it.

```
var arr = [null];
arr = arr.concat(data);
```

Comment: or `var arr = [null].concat(data);` for prettiness

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

`x = [null].concat([1, 2, 3]);`

Though there isn't anything wrong with doing something like:

`x[index-1]`

I'd prefer it to be honest, otherwise someone might assume that the index value returned is 0 based.