# Add item on specific position of JQuery array

Tags: jquery

I got the following array:

```
var liList = $(".paging li");
```

Right now it's filled like this: `["Previous", "Next"]`.
Now I want to add numbers between those two items to get something like `["Previous", "1", "2", "Next"]`.
 How do I do this? I want something like this:

```
var liList = $(".paging li");
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++){
    liList.eq(i).add("li");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/insert-item-into-array-at-a-specific-index, the keyword you are looking for is 'insert/insertion'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [array_splice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) function:

```
$(function() {
    var pagination = ["Previous", "Next"];
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++ ) {
        pagination.splice(i, 0, i);
    }
    console.log(pagination);
});
```

Output is:

```
 ["Previous", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "Next"]
```

Comment: This doesn't work with a JQuery array, does it? Or am I doing something else wrong?