# Javascript push multidimensional array only checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have checkboxes on page and i want to POST only checked values onchange each checkbox

```
$(function () {
    $('.list input').change(function (e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        var favorite = [];
        $.each($(".list input[type='checkbox']:checked"), function () {
            favorite[$(this).attr("name")].push = $(this).val();
        });

        var str;
        str = $.param(favorite);

        $.ajax({
            url: '/schema.asp',
            type: 'POST',
            data: str,
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

But I cant do right syntax to push checked to array

```
$.each($(".list input[type='checkbox']:checked"), function () {
    favorite[$(this).attr("name")].push = $(this).val();
});
```

Please show the right way.

$(this).attr("name") can vary from (Make[],Model[],Year()) and must be a string

SOLVED:

As nobody answer with full answer, this is finall working code

```
    $(function () {
        $('.list input').change(function (e) {
            //e.preventDefault();
            var favorite = {};
            $.each($(".list input[type='checkbox']:checked"), function(){ 
            if(typeof(favorite[$(this).attr("name")]) == 'undefined'){
                favorite[$(this).attr("name")] = [];
            }           
            favorite[$(this).attr("name")].push($(this).val());
        });

            var str;
            str = $.param(favorite);

            $.ajax({
                url: '/schema.asp',
                type: 'POST',
                data: str,
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert Item into Array at a Specific Index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/insert-item-into-array-at-a-specific-index)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is a function to be called, **not** a property to be set

```
var favorite = {};
$.each($(".list input[type='checkbox']:checked"), function(){ 
    if(typeof(favorite[$(this).attr("name")]) == 'undefined'){
        favorite[$(this).attr("name")] = [];
    }           
    favorite[$(this).attr("name")].push($(this).val());
});
```

Also, note above you need to check if that property for the object has been set or not in order to initialize it as an array.

```js
$('.list input').change(function(e) {
  //e.preventDefault();
  var favorite = [];
   $.each($(".list input[type='checkbox']:checked"), function(){ 
                if(typeof(favorite[$(this).attr("name")]) == 'undefined'){
                    favorite[$(this).attr("name")] = [];
                }           
                favorite[$(this).attr("name")].push($(this).val());
            });
  console.log(favorite);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="one" value="1" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="two" value="2" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="one" value="1" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="two" value="2" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="one" value="1" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin, it is giving that exception because at that point in execution `favorite[$(this).attr("name")]` **is** undefined

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin, it would have happened if you tried any other property like `favorite[$(this).attr("name")].wakawaka = 1;`

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: favorite is not defined

Comment: `$(this).attr("name")` must be a number (or string number) like `1` or `"1"`. If `$(this).attr("name")` is a string like `"foo"` or `"01"` this code not works.

Comment: if `$(this).attr("name")` is a string like `foo`  `favorite` must be an object `{}` not an array `[]`

Comment: Sigh, somebody downvoted, do they care to explain why?

Comment: I edit your answer to add a short version of your code and the correct definition of `favorite`. UPVOTE.

Comment: @Frogmouth, I appreciate the upvote and edit. However, I took the first part `var favorite = {};` but left the last part as I beleive this is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

use **[map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)** in jquery .Translate all items in an array or object to new array of items.

```
favorite = $(".list input[type='checkbox']:checked").map(function () {
    var obj = {};
    obj[$(this).attr("name")] = this.value;
    return obj;

}).get();
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vb1szd8n/1/)**

Comment: NOTE the use of an `Object` instead a `Array` , `$(this).attr("name")` could be different to a number. It's prevent a lot of error. Nice!

Comment: always return undefined in POST request