# javascript - sort javascript array of objects based on the value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I've got an array of object like this:

```
{"aid":1,"id":51,"modifier":5},
{"aid":2,"id":51,"modifier":5},
{"aid":3,"id":51,"modifier":2},
{"aid":4,"id":51,"modifier":3},
{"aid":5,"id":51,"modifier":3}
```

I will add an object `{"aid":6,"id":51,"modifier":5}` , the array now will look like this:

```
{"aid":1,"id":51,"modifier":5},
{"aid":2,"id":51,"modifier":5},
{"aid":3,"id":51,"modifier":2},
{"aid":4,"id":51,"modifier":3},
{"aid":5,"id":51,"modifier":3},
{"aid":6,"id":51,"modifier":5}
```

But i want to know is how i will push the new object `{"aid":6,"id":51,"modifier":5}` not into the last index of the array, but base on the `modifier`, that will look like this:

```
{"aid":1,"id":51,"modifier":5},
{"aid":2,"id":51,"modifier":5},
{"aid":6,"id":51,"modifier":5}
{"aid":3,"id":51,"modifier":2},
{"aid":4,"id":51,"modifier":3},
{"aid":5,"id":51,"modifier":3},
```

I dont know if it is possible, can somebdy solve this. Thanks

Comment: How is it sorted? 5 - 2 - 3? What way of sorting is that?

Comment: What is the exact logic? how can you decide 5 will go before the 2 and not after the 3? Or is it that you want the same modifier grouped together without a specific order? If so why does it hurt to sort it?

Comment: So you want to insert the new item after the last item with a similar modifier? That's all well and good, but then what happens next time? After `aid:6` is added, and you reload the data, what do you want the list to look like?

Comment: Find the last index of your modifier and splice it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/how-do-i-insert-an-item-into-an-array-at-a-specific-index

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a custom comparison function to Array.sort
e.g

```
list.sort(function (a, b) {
  if (a.modifier > b.modifier) {
    return 1;
  }
  return -1;
});
```

I am not sure what the logic behind your search order is, but if you can write a a comparison function you can sort by it.

Answer (score 0):

I notice your *Objects* seem to be sorted by both *modifier* and *aid*. This means you want to sort by multiple properties. Write a comparator like this

```
function comparator(keys, a, b) {
    var k, key, mod = [1, -1], order;
    for (k = 0; k < keys.length; ++k) {
        key = keys[k].key;
        order = !keys[k].descending;
        if (b[key] > a[key]) return order ? -1 : 1;
        else if (b[key] < a[key]) return  order ? 1 : -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now say your *Array* is called `foo`, `.bind` the comparator with your key weightings as you pass it into `foo.sort`

```
foo.sort(
    comparator.bind(null, [
        {key: 'modifier', descending: true},
        {key: 'aid'},
    ])
);
```

Comment: i want to try this, but what are the key, a, b parameter? is, k is array, is b is value or?

Comment: @remolalata `a` and `b` are two elements, used by `sort`, `keys` is an _Array of Objects_ you supply, such as the example shown :)