# How to sort an array of objects based on the substring of property values

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I sort the following array, in a custom order, based on the `prop2`'s last 3 letters that have to be in this order 'ABR', 'FDE', 'ZFR' and also in descending order 'ZFR', 'FDE', 'ARB' for another array.

Sample input:

```
const arr = [
  { prop1: 3, prop2: '3FDE' },
  { prop1: 4, prop2: '5ZFR' },
  { prop1: 5, prop2: '7ABR' }
]
```

Expected output:

```
const arr1 = [
  { prop1: 5, prop2: '7ABR' },
  { prop1: 3, prop2: '3FDE' },
  { prop1: 4, prop2: '5ZFR' }
]

and

const arr2 = [
  { prop1: 4, prop2: '5ZFR' },
  { prop1: 3, prop2: '3FDE' },
  { prop1: 5, prop2: '7ABR' }
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript - sort javascript array of objects based on the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208242/javascript-sort-javascript-array-of-objects-based-on-the-value)

Comment: Yes, this will answer to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), iterate over the array to sort it
- In every iteration, use [`String#substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) to get the last 3 characters and [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to compare the two strings

```js
const arr = [ { prop1: 3, prop2: '3FDE' }, { prop1: 4, prop2: '5ZFR' }, { 
prop1: 5, prop2: '7ABR' } ];

const _getLastThree = (str = '') => str.substr(str.length - 3);
const res = arr.sort(({ prop2: a }, { prop2: b }) => 
  _getLastThree(a).localeCompare(_getLastThree(b))
);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know how to sort it also descending? In this order '5ZFR','3FDE','7ARB'?

Comment: @ryy77 you're welcome, just swap: `_getLastThree(b).localeCompare(_getLastThree(a))`

Comment: This approach _does_ work. However, please note that `String.substr` is marked as deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.localeCompare()` in combination with `.slice()`:

```js
const arr=[
{prop1:5, prop2:'7ABR'},
{prop1:3, prop2:'3FDE'},
{prop1:4, prop2:'5ZFR'},
]


var ascArr,dscArr;
console.log(ascArr=arr.slice(0).sort((a,b)=>a.prop2.slice(-3).localeCompare(b.prop2.slice(-3))));

// for descending order just do 
console.log(dscArr=arr.slice(0).sort((a,b)=>-a.prop2.slice(-3).localeCompare(b.prop2.slice(-3))));

// or reverse the resulting array with 
console.log(dscArr=ascArr.reverse());
```

Please note that the two `slice()` methods belong to *different prototypes*: `.slice(0)` is an `Array` method that essentially creates a flat copy of the original array while `.slice(-3)` is a `String` method that "shaves off" the last three characters of the string.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know how to sort it also descending? In this order '5ZFR','3FDE','7ARB'?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Array#sort`, `String#substring` or `String#slice` or `String#substr` and the `String#localCompare` methods as follows:

- `substring`

```js
const arr = [ {prop1:4, prop2:'5ZFR'}, {prop1:5, prop2:'7ABR'}, {prop1:3, prop2:'3FDE'} ];

const output = arr.sort(
   (a,b) => 
   a.prop2.substring(1).localeCompare( b.prop2.substring(1) )
);

console.log( output );
```

With `slice` or `substr` you can use a negative n to indicate the last n characters:

```js
const arr = [ {prop1:4, prop2:'5ZFR'}, {prop1:5, prop2:'7ABR'}, {prop1:3, prop2:'3FDE'} ];

const output = arr.sort(
   (a,b) => 
   a.prop2.slice(-3).localeCompare( b.prop2.slice(-3) )
);

console.log( output );
```