# Insert an object before selected object in array

Tags: angularjs, object

Hy,

I have an angular application.
There is a case where i get an object by click on it and this object is in an array.
So by example i have:
newObject: {object3}
arrayOfObjects: [{object1}, {object2}, ....]

So when i select {object2} i want to put newObject before or after {object2}

I tried with indexOf() to get the index of the object to go trough but indexOf() seems not to be working in this case.

I have a solution to get the parent of selected object so now i only need to find a way to put my new object in position.
Maybe there is an angular way for this?
Or something else?
underscore maybe?

Answer (score 0):

*Adding as answer as I dont have enough points to comment.*

Hi Bert,

Are you looking for something like this? [How to insert an item into an array at a specific index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/how-to-insert-an-item-into-an-array-at-a-specific-index)

Comment: No,
because i dont know the index of my object in the array.
array.indexOf(object) also doesnt work because indexOf only seems to be working on values in an array.