# Push an object in a specific order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object, let's say

```
var obj = [{"name": "banana", "type": "fruit"},
           {"name": "carrot", "type": "vegetable"}];
```

And I need to add an object right after the first one [0]
so I'll get the following:

```
var obj = [{"name": "banana", "type": "fruit"},
           {"name": "apple", "type": "fruit"},
           {"name": "carrot", "type": "vegetable"}];
```

needless to say I want it dynamic, and I'm trying to avoid loops for ease of use later down the road...

Is there any function like

```
obj.pushAfter(this['type'], "fruit", {"name": "apple", "type": "fruit"});
```

Type of function?
P.S I'm using Jquery so that's an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your talking about pushing into an **array**, not an object.  The two are different animals, and it's important you understand their differences.

What you want is the splice function on the native array object.
arr.splice(index, 0, item); will insert item into arr at the specified index.

Source: [How to insert an item into an array at a specific index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/how-to-insert-an-item-into-an-array-at-a-specific-index)

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: Ride on, you solved it! Thank you for the detailed answer :)

Comment: Array is a type of object in javascript. use `typeof []` and you get to know

Comment: @gal zakay, I'm glad it worked out for you.  If you are satisfied with this answer, could you please accept it as correct.  Thanks!

Comment: Had to wait for a few minutes but I did, Thanks again and thank you Garvit for the additional info

Answer (score 2):

While the accepted answer is informative and leads you to the right direction, if you are actually in need if a `pushAfter` function that does exactly what you described, you could roll your own like so...

```
function pushAfter(coll, k, v, add) {
  var matchIndex = coll.reduce(function(prevVal, currVal, i, arr) {
    if (currVal[k] === v) {
      return i;
    }
  });

  coll.splice(matchIndex + 1, 0, add);
}

var obj = [{"name": "banana", "type": "fruit"},
           {"name": "carrot", "type": "vegetable"}];

pushAfter(obj, 'type', "fruit", {"name": "apple", "type": "fruit"});
pushAfter(obj, 'name', "carrot", {"name": "radish", "type": "vegetable"});
```

This would yield:

```
[{
  name: "apple",
  type: "fruit"
}, {
  name: "banana",
  type: "fruit"
}, {
  name: "carrot",
  type: "vegetable"
}, {
  name: "radish",
  type: "vegetable"
}]
```

This finds your specified key and value within the given collection and splices in the new item at the matched index. Leveraging `reduce` in this case also provides a simple way to identify the match's index. Additionally, here's a [working example](http://jsbin.com/mupodijake/edit?js,console).

Comment: That's simply amazing! just learned a lot from this comment, thank you very much!

Comment: I'm happy to help. Let me know if you try it out and how it works out. Also, as @tpdietz pointed out, if you find this helpful then it's great for the community if you upvote it :D

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = [{"name": "banana", "type": "fruit"},
           {"name": "carrot", "type": "vegetable"}];

// splice(position, numberOfItemsToRemove, item)
obj.splice(1, 0, {"name": "apple", "type": "fruit"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could a function for it. It searches for the right property `key` and insert the item after the group, before other groups have started.

This solution features [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), because it stops iterating if the wanted index is found.

```js
function pushAfter(array, key, item) {
    var index = 0;
    array.some(function (a, i) {
        if (a[key] === item[key]) {
            index = i + 1;
            return false;
        }
        return index;
    });
    array.splice(index, 0, item);
}

var array = [{ "name": "banana", "type": "fruit" }, { "name": "carrot", "type": "vegetable" }];
pushAfter(array, 'type', { "name": "apple", "type": "fruit" });

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing a sorted push will only work if the array is already sorted correctly, so if you always start with an empty or sorted array and the array is only mutated by the `pushAfter` function, then you're fine. However, if you retrieve the array from an external API, it can be modified outside of your `pushAfter` function, or you are otherwise unable to guarantee that the array will always be sorted before you push to it, you can't guarantee that a `pushAfter` function will always provide a sorted array.

For example, if you start with an array with objects sorted in the order of `fruit, fruit, vegetable, fruit`, the above `pushAfter` function will result in the array sorted as `fruit, fruit, vegetable, fruit, fruit` instead of `fruit, fruit, fruit, fruit, vegetable`. A method that will always be reliable would be to do a regular `push` and then `sort` the array.

```js
function sortedPush(sourceArray, newObject) {
  sourceArray.push(newObject);

  sourceArray.sort(function(a, b) {
 // returns 0 if both objects have equal type
 //         1 if a is greater than b (should be sorted after)
 //        -1 if a is less than b (should be sorted before)
 return (a.type === b.type) ? 0 : a.type > b.type;
  });
}

var unsortedArray = [{
  "name": "banana",
  "type": "fruit"
}, {
  "name": "carrot",
  "type": "vegetable"
}, {
  "name": "grape",
  "type": "fruit"
}];

sortedPush(unsortedArray, {
  "name": "orange",
  "type": "fruit"
});

console.log(unsortedArray);
```

`unsortedArray` after the sorted push:

```
[{
  name: "banana",
  type: "fruit"
},  {
  name: "grape",
  type: "fruit"
},  {
  name: "orange",
  type: "fruit"
},  {
  name: "carrot",
  type: "vegetable"
}]
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/jawezaroma/edit?js,console)

See documentation for [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)