# Add attribute/element to existing javascript array

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript object

```
const categories = Object.keys(titles);
```

that looks like this

```
["scifi","horror","comedy"]
```

I want to add "drama" to the object. I've tried

```
categories['drama'];
```

but that doesn't work. How can I add another category to this categories object?

Comment: I'm voting to close. Read the fine manual ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: FYI, `categories` is an `Array`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: Or there is also [How to insert an item into an array at a specific index?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/586182/1529630)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an array of object keys so you need to use **[`Array#push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)** method

```
categories.push('drama');
```

```js
const categories = ["scifi", "horror", "comedy"];

categories.push('drama');

console.log(categories);
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! Also, how would iI remove something from an array?

Comment: @Modelesq : `splice()` method can be used