# Javascript: conditional row in array

Tags: javascript

If I have an array built like so:

```
body: [
  [ 'A', 'A value' ],
  [ 'B', 'B value, other' ],
  [ 'C', 'C value' ]
]
```

How can wrap an if statement around the `C` so that the row is only added if the condition returns true? Something like this (pseudocode):

```
body: [
  [ 'A', 'A value' ],
  [ 'B', 'B value, other' ],
  if (x == true) {
    [ 'C', 'C value' ]
  }
]
```

Comment: I just want to clarify. Is this an array of arrays? Or is it supposed to be an array of objects?

Comment: @giovannilobitos it changes nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid pushing the item after the array initilizer, you may prefer

```
body: [
  [ 'A', 'A value' ],
  [ 'B', 'B value, other' ],
  x == true && [ 'C', 'C value' ]
].filter(Boolean)
```

That is, let the third array item be `[ 'C', 'C value' ]` only if `x == true` is `true`. If it's `false`, let the third array item be `false`.

And then filter out all falsy values: `null`, `undefined`, `false`, `+0`, `-0`, `NaN` and `""`. So only use this approach if your array doesn't contain any of these.

Answer (score 4):

Just `push` it.

```
if (x) {
    yourReference.body.push([ 'C', 'C value' ]);
}
```

Comment: [push it real good](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vCadcBR95oU)!

Comment: This is what I thought, but is there something more "inline"? The object I'm dealing with is big, and there are a lot of body elements.

Comment: @CD-RUM there is no *easy and robust* way to do that directly in the array literal.

Comment: @CD-RUM nothing in pure javascript. if this was coming from a templating engine, then maybe

Comment: @CD-RUM: You could add a filter afterwards, but I’d advise against it: `[…, x ? ['C', 'C value'] : null, …].filter(Boolean)` (where you can check for `=== null` if falsy values are valid, and use `undefined` if `null` is valid, and use a new object if both are valid).

Comment: After the array has been created, you can use `splice` to insert an element at a specific index - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/how-to-insert-an-item-into-an-array-at-a-specific-index

Answer (score 1):

You could also make a builder:

```
function ArrayBuilder() {
    this.array = [];
}

ArrayBuilder.prototype.push = function (value) {
    this.array.push(value);
    return this;
};

ArrayBuilder.prototype.pushIf = function (condition, value) {
    if (condition) {
        this.array.push(value);
    }

    return this;
};
```

although this means your value is always evaluated, regardless of the condition.

```
body: new ArrayBuilder()
    .push([ 'A', 'A value' ])
    .push([ 'B', 'B value, other' ])
    .pushIf(x, [ 'C', 'C value' ])
    .array,
```

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through all the elements in the body and condition each.

```
const body = [

  [ 'A', 'A value' ],
  [ 'B', 'B value, other' ],
  [ 'C', 'C value' ]

];

const newArray = body.map(subArray => {

  if (condition) return subArray;  

});
```