# How to find end of hour and push an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a sample array below. I want to check in every hour if I have a object at last minute and if its not there I want to push one. 
For example, in the below array we see that there is an object at 02:55 and 03:50 but I do not have an object at 00:50 and 01:50. SO how can I push an object for those times.

```
[{day: "2016-10-27T00:45:00.000Z", time: "00:45", val: 100}
{day: "2016-10-27T02:00:00.000Z", time: "02:00", val: 100}
{day: "2016-10-27T02:30:00.000Z", time: "02:30", val: 100}
{day: "2016-10-27T02:55:00.000Z", time: "02:55", val: 100}
{day: "2016-10-27T03:00:00.000Z", time: "03:00", val: 100}
{day: "2016-10-27T03:00:00.000Z", time: "03:00", val: 100}
{day: "2016-10-27T03:00:00.000Z", time: "03:00", val: 100}
{day: "2016-10-27T03:00:00.000Z", time: "03:00", val: 100}
{day: "2016-10-27T03:15:00.000Z", time: "03:15", val: 100}
{day: "2016-10-27T03:30:00.000Z", time: "03:30", val: 100}
{day: "2016-10-27T03:30:00.000Z", time: "03:30", val: 100}
{day: "2016-10-27T03:40:00.000Z", time: "03:40", val: 100}
{day: "2016-10-27T03:50:00.000Z", time: "03:50", val: 100}
{day: "2016-10-27T04:00:00.000Z", time: "04:00", val: 100}]
```

Can somebody help me with this please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/how-to-insert-an-item-into-an-array-at-a-specific-index

Comment: How do you define "missing"? It's trivial to do it in this case if you just insert something as the second item in the array, but I'm guessing you want a more general answer.

Comment: I read this as "I need to add an object to this array and then sort the array by time, ascending". Is that correct. If so, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10124053/1195835

Comment: @vlaz you are right I am having tough time finding an object missing at in a given array

Comment: @TecBrat I already have a sorted array. I am having missing values randomly at different hours and minutes so I want to add a point very hour with val 80

Answer (score 0):

Adds new object to array:

```
arr.push({day: "2016-10-27T01:00:00.000Z", time: "01:00", val: 80})
```

Comment: I have values that are missing at different times. How can I add a value for every hour ?

Answer (score 0):

Adds new object to array and sorts it on date

```
arr.push({day: "2016-10-27T01:00:00.000Z", time: "01:00", val: 80});
arr.sort((a,b) => Date.parse(a.day)-Date.parse(b.day));
```

Comment: Thank Kevin for this answer. But I am trying to push an object every hour like 01:00, 02:00,03:00 and so on. If I have value missing at 6:00 then I want to push an object with a value at that particular hour

Comment: Kevin's solution is exactly what I suggested. Just do this for each time that is missing. pablopunk has given you a function to see if the value is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a forEach loop:

```
var foundIt = false;
myArray.forEach(function(element) {
  if (element.time == whatEverIWant) { // missing time
    foundIt = true;
  }
}

if (!foundIt) {
  myArray.push({ /* insert the missing object here */ });
}

// optionally, sort the array by time
myArray.sort(function(a,b) { return a.time.localeCompare(b.time); }
```

In case you wanna do this for multiple values, just run the code inside another for loop with each value.