# Insert in a specific position on array without deleting the element in JS

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
var array = [3,5,6,2,1];
```

I want to insert `7` inside the **first position** without deleting `3` so the resulting array would be this:

```
array = [7,3,5,6,2,1];
```

Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert an item into an array at a specific index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/how-to-insert-an-item-into-an-array-at-a-specific-index)

Comment: @Epitouille i don't want to delete the element of the specific index

Comment: @OiRc Read the link Epitouille showed, it clearly shows how to insert not just replace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to enter only in first position.

You can use [**unshift**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift?v=example)

```js
var x = [3, 5, 6, 2, 1];
x.unshift(7);
console.log(x)
```

If the element(which is to be insert) is inside another array, [**Spread_operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) can come handy

```js
var a = [7];
var x = [...a, 3, 5, 6, 2, 1];
console.log(x)
```

Comment: thanks in advance, you save my day, i didn't know about unshift

Comment: What about inserting anywhere in general? That's what the question actually is asking for !!

Answer (score 5):

Use the `Splice` method:

```js
var array = [3, 5, 6, 2, 1];
array.splice(0, 0, 7);

array.splice('index', 'replace or not', 'item to insert');

=> [7, 3, 5, 6, 2, 1];

array.splice(3, 0, 7); => [3, 5, 7, 6, 2, 1];
```

Answer (score 3):

Splice method will be used for this.  `array.splice(0, 0, 7);`

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you need :

```
array.unshift(7);
```

Answer (score 1):

To put something inside the first position, you can use "unshift"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tab=new Array("Apple", "Pineapple", "Cherry");
tab.unshift("Banana", "Peach")
document.write(tab.join(", "));
</script>
```

And you get :

```
Banana, Peach, Apple, Pineapple, Cherry
```