# How to push new key value pair in existing javascript object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have defined array of object something like this:

```
  this.choices =  [
        {
            id: 0,
            product: [{id:'0'}] 
        }
        ];
```

Now I want to insert new key-value pair in choices :

```
                    [
                    {
                        id: 10,
                        product: [{id:'5'}] 
                    }
                    ]
```

I tried to do it by push() method but I guess its for Array only. Please help me with same. Thank you so much in advance. :)
Also, Is it possible to push these key-pair value at certain index for these array of objects.

Comment: how did you try with push?

Comment: I did something like this :
   this.choices.push( [
         {
             id: '10',
             product: [{id:'5'}] ,
         }
         ]);
    }

I guess extra square bracket was causing problem.

Answer (score 2):

This should work,

```
this.choices.push({id: 10,product: [{id:'5'}]});
```

Comment: I was trying to do the same but I added [] after push. Thank you so much. :)
Bdw Is it possible to push these key-pair value at certain index?

Comment: yes you can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/how-to-insert-an-item-into-an-array-at-a-specific-index

Comment: But it is for array. I want to do same for array of objects in the form of key value pairs.

Comment: As suggested by you, If i want to access "id" value  with "Push" method:
All i have to do is "choices[1].id "
Right? Here index is "1" 
I want to change its index from 1 to some certain value lets say "10"

Answer (score 0):

Since both examples are actually arrays containing objects, you should be using `concat` rather than push. ie;

```
this.choices =  [
        {
            id: 0,
            product: [{id:'0'}] 
        }
        ];


var newVal =  [
                    {
                        id: 10,
                        product: [{id:'5'}] 
                    }
                    ];


this.choices = this.choices.concat(newVal);
```

In my example, to use push you'd need to do `this.choices.push(newVal[0])` - many ways to approach it but basically, push is for individual values, concat is for arrays.