# Add element for object

Tags: javascript

I need to go through a list of objects to find the element and add a new element to the root, I can scroll through the list and find the element, but I can not add to the correct level

```
var data = [

    {
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 6
            },
            {
                "id": 7                    
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 5
    }

];

function findById(data, id, element) {
    function iter(a) {
        if (a.id === id) {
            a.push(element); // ERROR
            result = a;
            return true;
        }
        return Array.isArray(a.children) && a.children.some(iter);
    }
    var result;
    data.some(iter);
    return result
}


var element = {
    "children": [{"id": 6}]
};

findById(data, 5, element);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4nrsccnu/

Comment: a.push does nothing because it isn't an array. Try pushing to the array.

Comment: `a.push` throws error because `a` is object not containing array. You need to use `Array.indexOf` to get the location of `a` in `data`. Then refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/how-to-insert-an-item-into-an-array-at-a-specific-index

Comment: You may be trying to do this though: `a.children.push` instead of `a.push` This will, in your example make the object with id of 5 have children with element of id 6.

Comment: What is the result you're trying to get? `{ "id": 5, "children": [ {"id": 6} ] }`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `push`, because `a` is an object.  However, you can simply add the desired property (in your case, `children`), and then assign it a value (in your case, the `element`).

```js
var data = [

    {
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 6
            },
            {
                "id": 7                    
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 5
    }

];

function findById(data, id, element) {
    function iter(a) {
        if (a.id === id) {
            a.children = element;  // Add property 'children'
            result = a;
            return true;
        }
        return Array.isArray(a.children) && a.children.some(iter);
    }
    var result;
    data.some(iter);
    return result
}

// remove property name from element, as that is being added in the function
var element = [
    {"id": 6}
];

findById(data, 5, element);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.assign` to merge the properties from the `element` object to the current object of the iteration.

```js
var data = [

    {
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 6
            },
            {
                "id": 7                    
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 5
    }

];

function findById(data, id, element) {
    function iter(a) {
        if (a.id === id) {
            Object.assign(a, element);
            result = a;
            return true;
        }
        return Array.isArray(a.children) && a.children.some(iter);
    }
    var result;
    data.some(iter);
    return result
}


var element = {
    "children": [{"id": 6}]
};

findById(data, 5, element);

console.log(data);
```

Comment: I need a structure that will mount a tree of objects, I got this way where you pass the parent id and the element to be inserted, could you please evaluate if this is the best way to do it.

https://jsfiddle.net/5ajxhwx3/2/

Comment: That seems fine. The `element` parameter to the function is different from what you showed in the question. It means the function can only add children, not other properties, but it works to add additional children to node that already has children.

Comment: Yes and for that same add children and sibling to the elements

Answer (score 1):

The `push` function is used for `arrays`, not to object. Check for details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push.

If you want to add a single keypair to your object, you can use `Object.keys` and `Object.values`. Like this:

```
function findById(data, id, element) {
    function iter(a) {
        if (a.id === id) {
            var key = Object.keys(element)[0];
            var value = Object.values(element)[0];
            a[key] = value;
            result = a;
            return true;
        }
        return Array.isArray(a.children) && a.children.some(iter);
    }

    var result;
    data.some(iter);
    return result;
}
```