# Update javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I just started a couple of weeks ago with javascript. How can I add or editing elements to this array:

```
var array = [["A1","B1","C1"],
             ["A2","B2","C2"],
             ["A3","B3","C3"],
             ["A4","B4","C4"],
             ["A5","B5","C5"],
             ["A1","B1","C1"],
             ["A2","B2","C2"],
             ["A3","B3","C3"],
             ["A4","B4","C4"],
           ];
```

For example, I want to add `["C1", "C2", "C3"]` or update the second line to `["Z1" , "Z2", "Z3"]`

Comment: For adding elements to array refer: [PUSH](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) or To add element to a specific posotion in array refer: [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/586189/2968762)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access the topmost array, you can `push` or `pop`or a number of other native array methods. You can access the inner arrays by index (array[0] for example), and then use regular array methods on the inner arrays. You can read more about arrays and their methods [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)

To answer your two examples, to add a new array, you'd `array.push(newArray)` where newArray is the array you wanted to insert, `["C1", "C2", "C3"]`, if you wanted to update the second line, you could access it by index `array[1]` and set it equal to a new value, `array[1] =  ["Z1" , "Z2", "Z3"]`

Comment: How can I figure it out what the index of the array is when I just know a unique value ist for example Z1?

Answer (score -1):

```
array.push(["C1", "C2", "C3"] );

array[1] = ["Z1" , "Z2", "Z3"];
```