# How can i target the second letter of a div using jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day,

How can i target the second letter of a div that the value is being get through API.

```
<div>example</div>
```

**example** is data that is being get through API and i want to add styling just in the second letter on it. how can i do that?

Comment: Get string in var and get second letter then apply CSS using JS/jQuery

Comment: Replace the textContent with `e<span class="target">x</span>ample`. How to do it? - Use `text()` to get textContent, string methods to get second character, update the innerHTML.

Comment: how can i get the string method to get the 2nd char? do i need to use substr()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string which will create an array of characters, then at the specified index add the HTML tag and the character.Use `join` to create the string again and `replace` method to replace comma (`'`)

```js
// creating an array the characters
var splitString = document.getElementById('textContent').innerHTML.split('');
// targeting the character at index 1
splitString[1] = '<span class ="custom">x</span>'
document.getElementById('textContent').innerHTML = splitString.join('').replace(/,/g, '')
```

```css
.custom {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div id="textContent">example</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is example :

```js
var string = $('div').text(), t;

/*  
    1st letter - string.substr(0,1)
    2nd letter - string.substr(1,1) 
    2nd onwards - string.substr(2)
*/
t = string.substr(0,1) + '<span class="test">'+ string.substr(1,1) + '</span>' + string.substr(2);
   
console.log(t);
$('div').html(t);
```

```css
.test{
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>example</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to know that there is a [::first-letter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter) pseudo-element in CSS, which unfortunately won't help you. And it only works on block-level elements.

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

for (var el of divs) {
  var text = el.textContent;
  el.innerHTML = text[0] + '<span>' + text[1] + '</span>' + text.substring(2);
}
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>example1</div>
<div>example2</div>
```

Comment: this seems work, but how can i apply when there is multiple data on it? example <div>example1</div><div>example2</> ... and more. and i just want to color all 2nd letter on it.

Comment: @JydonMah Use querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

You can use prototype to replace char at index with with style content.

```js
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, replaceChar) {
    var a = this.split("");
    a[index] = replaceChar;
    return a.join("");
}

var result ="example";
var secondChar = result.charAt(1);
var updatedContent = result.replaceAt(1, '<span class="test">'+secondChar+'</span>');
console.log(updatedContent);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `splice` on array object to insert an element in a specific index, in this case 1. Index 3 for the second time because index is shifted by one place.

`arr.splice(index, 0, item)` will insert item into arr at the specified index (deleting 0 items first, that is, it's just an insert).
[Found it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/586189/2126488).

```
var str = document.getElementById('test').innerText().split('');
str.splice(1, 0, '<span class="colored">');
str.splice(3, 0, '</span>');
document.getElementById('test').innerText = str.join('');
```

```
.colored {
 color: blue;
}
```

```
<div id='test'>example</div>
```