# Increase value of item in Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have Javascript array that looks like this:

```
 fruitsGroups: [
    "apple0",
    "banana0",
    "pear0",
  ]
```

How can I increase the number of each item in this array?

```
 fruitsGroups: [

    "apple0",
    "apple1",
    "apple2",

    "banana0",
    "banana1",
    "banana2",

    "pear0",
    "pear1",
    "pear2"
  ]
```

Comment: Nothing about that is specifically more jQuery than it is just javascript.

Comment: Using a loop. What have you tried?

Comment: @j08691 I am not sure how I can use loop to push elements in array

Comment: @Taplar this is a small fragment from the whole jQuery code

Comment: This fragment is showing a part of an object that has a key with a value of an array.  Both objects and arrays, plain javascript, not jQuery.  My point being you are asking about a javascript logic issue, and framing it as a jQuery question, which it is not.

Comment: It seems that you forgot to include your own efforts, Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service, so please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49368412/edit) and add all relevant code that you already wrote into it. Also please see **[ask]**. And if needed, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/586182/1220550

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your looking for something like that?

```
var fruitsGroups = [
    "apple0",
    "banana0",
    "pear0",
  ];
  console.log(fruitsGroups);

  var newFruits = [];
  $.each(fruitsGroups, function(i, j) {
     var n = parseInt(j.substring(j.length - 1));
     for(var k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        newFruits.push(j.substring(0, j.length - 1) + (n + k));
     }
  });

  console.log(newFruits);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since we have 2018 already, another approach using Array.map and destructuring:

```
const groups = [
    "apple0",
    "banana0",
    "pear0",
  ];

[].concat(...groups.map(item => [
    item,
    item.replace(0, 1),
    item.replace(0, 2)
  ]
))

// result: ["apple0", "apple1", "apple2",
//          "banana0", "banana1", "banana2",
//          "pear0", "pear1", "pear2"]
```

Explanation:

`groups.map(item => [item, item.replace(0, 1), item.replace(0, 2)])` takes each array item one by one (`apple0`, then `banana0`, …) and replaces it with an array of:

- `item` – the item itself (`apple0`)
- `item.replace(0, 1)` – the item with zero replaced by `1` (`apple1`)
- `item.replace(0, 2)` – the item with zero replaced by `2` (`apple2`)

so the array looks like…

```
[
  ["apple0", "apple1", "apple2"],
  ["banana0", "banana1", "banana2"],
  ["pear0", "pear1", "pear2"],
]
```

…and then we need to flatten it, that's the `[].concat(...` part. It basically takes array items (the three dots, [read more about destructuring here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring)), and merges them into an empty array.

If you want to replace any digit, not just zero, use regular expression:

```
"apple0".replace(/\d$/, 1)
 // -> "apple1"
"apple9".replace(/\d$/, 1)
 // -> "apple1"
```

- `\d` – any number character
- `$` - end of line
- the surrounding slashes tell JS that it's a regular expression, you could use `new RegExp("\d$")` instead, too

Answer (score 1):

You could create function that uses `reduce()` method and returns new array.

```js
function mult(data, n) {
  return data.reduce((r, e) => {
    return r.push(e, ...Array.from(Array(n), (_, i) => {
      const [text, n] = e.split(/(\d+)/);
      return text + (+n + i + 1)
    })), r
  }, []);
}

console.log(mult(["apple0", "banana0", "pear0"], 2))
console.log(mult(["apple4", "banana2", "pear0"], 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this for you, it might help as per my understanding. Naive Approach

```js
var a = ['apple0','banana0','pearl0']
var fruitGroups = []
for(var i=0; i < a.length; i++){
 for(var j = 0; j<a.length; j++){
   let fruit = a[i].replace(/\d/g,'')+j
   fruitGroups.push(fruit)
  }
}
console.log(fruitGroups)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the original array. For each item, create a sub array, and [fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) it with the current item. Then map the sub array and [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) the digit/s of each item with the index. Flatten the sub arrays, by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) into [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
const fruitsGroups = [
  "apple0",
  "banana0",
  "pear0",
];

const len = 3;
// map the original array, and use concat to flatten the sub arrays
const result = [].concat(...fruitsGroups.map((item) => 
  new Array(len) // create a new sub array with the requested size
  .fill(item) // fill it with the item
  .map((s, i) => s.replace(/\d+/, i)) // map the strings in the sub array, and replace the number with the index
));

console.log(result);
```