# Array Typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have an array called numbers.

```
numbers = [1,2,3,...,8,9,10]
```

But In the middle of the array, I want to insert section of value, for example: `a,b,c` where `a,b,c` are under list no `5`.

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,a,b,c,6,7,...]
```

Actually, I want to make a multilevel list

```html
1
2
3
4
5
  a
  b
  c
6
7
8
9
10
```

Any idea or help will really be appreciated

Comment: Tell us what have you tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert an item into an array at a specific index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/how-to-insert-an-item-into-an-array-at-a-specific-index)

Comment: @syntagma I have been watching tuts for multidimensional array. am i on the right direction?

Comment: @noorayu, you are dealing with one-dimensional array, so no. It would help if you would show some us code.