# how do I insert dashes between each two even digits of a specific number

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to insert dash(-) between two even numbers.
Problem is dashes don't locate between two even numbers but at the end of the number.

here is the code

```
function insertHyphen(str) {
  var strArr = str.split('');
  var numArr = strArr.map(Number);
  for(var i = 0; i < numArr.length; i++) {
   if(numArr[i-1]%2===0 && numArr[i]%2===0) {
        numArr.push('-');
    }
  }
  return numArr.join('');
}
insertHyphen('112233445566'); // 112233445566---
```

Comment: Push inserts at the end of array only.

Comment: You need to use `splice()`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/how-to-insert-an-item-into-an-array-at-a-specific-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
numArr.push('-');
```

with

```
numArr.splice(i, 0, '-');
```

Comment: Someone answered just that 9 minutes earlier - o.O

Answer (score 3):

Use `splice()` instead of `push()`. See here  [Splice MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
function insertHyphen(str) {
  var strArr = str.split('');
  var numArr = strArr.map(Number);
    for(var i = 0; i < numArr.length; i++) {
      if(numArr[i-1]%2===0 && numArr[i]%2===0) {
        numArr.splice(i, 0, '-');
      }
    }
  return numArr.join('');
}
console.log(insertHyphen('112233445566')); // 112-2334-4556-6
```

Answer (score 3):

Using regex:

```
var p = '112233445566';

var regex = /([02468])([02468])/g

console.log(p.replace(regex, '$1-$2'));
```

Try it online: https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f@/LLFIoUDBVkHd0NDIyNjYxMTU1MxM3ZqLCyRRlJqeWgGU1NeINjAyMbOI1YQz9NO5uJLz84rzc1L1cvLTNQr0ilILchKTUzXAmnQU1FUMdVWM1DU1rbn@/wcA

Comment: Please provide executable code snippet here itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
function insertHyphen(str) {
  var strArr = str.split('');
  var numArr = strArr.map(Number);
    for(var i = 0; i < numArr.length; i++) {
      if(numArr[i-1]%2===0 && numArr[i]%2===0) {
        numArr.splice(i, 0, '-');
      }
    }
  return numArr.join('');
}
console.log(insertHyphen('025468 '));
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert number to String
2. keep first element of array into separate array i.e. newArray
3. Run the loop on string length
4. Check current and the next element is divisible by 2 or not. If yes, push '-' else push the next item.
5. Finally join the array elements of newArray with ''.

```
    let a = 224578;
    let str = a.toString()
    var newArray=[arr[0]]
    if(arr?.length > 0){
            
            for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if(arr[i] % 2 === 0 && arr[i+1] % 2 === 0){
                    newArray.push('-', arr[i+1])
                } else{
                    newArray.push(arr[i+1])
                }
            }
        }

    console.log('newArray', newArray.join(''))
```

Answer (score 0):

`Push` inserts element at the end of the array. You can use `splice` to enter element at particular position.

```
arr.splice(index, 0, item);
```

Here index is the position where you want to insert `item` element. And `0` represents without deleting 0 elements.

```js
function insertHyphen(str) {
  var strArr = str.split('');
  var numArr = strArr.map(Number);
  for(var i = 0; i < numArr.length; i++) {
   if(numArr[i-1]%2===0 && numArr[i]%2===0) {
        numArr.splice(i, 0, '-');
    }
  }
  return numArr.join('');
}

console.log(insertHyphen('112233445566'));
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way:

```js
function insertHyphen(str) {
  var strArr = str.split('');
  var numArr = strArr.map(Number);
  var result ="";
  for(var i = 0; i < numArr.length; i++) {
   if((numArr[i+1]!==undefined)&&(numArr[i]%2===0 && numArr[i+1]%2===0)) {
        //numArr.push('-');
        result = result + numArr[i] + "-";
    }else{
        result = result + numArr[i];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(insertHyphen('112233445566'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map the new string by check the value and predecessor.

```js
function insertHyphen(string) {
    return Array
        .from(string, (v, i) => !i || v % 2 || string[i - 1] % 2 ? v : '-' + v)
        .join('');
}

console.log(insertHyphen('22112233445566'));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Using push() method and single loop

```js
let input = '346845';
let result = [input[0]], 
len = input.length;

for (var i = 1; i < len; i++) {
  if (input[i - 1] % 2 === 0 && input[i] % 2 === 0) {
    result.push('-', input[i]);
  } else {
    result.push(input[i]);
  }
}
console.log(result.join(''));
```