# How to insert an item into an empty array at a specific index?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to insert a item to specified index of an empty Array. I saw there is   Array.prototype.splice method. However, if I use splice on empty Array, it just add item to end off Array as shown below.

```
var a = [];
a.splice(3,0,"item-3");
console.log(a); //returns ['item-3']
```

What I want to accomplish is to have array as given below.

```
console.log(a); //returns [,,,'item-3']
or
console.log(a); //returns [undefined,undefined,undefined,'item-3']
```

Thanks for your help.

Edit: I saw the question on [How to insert an item into an array at a specific index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/how-to-insert-an-item-into-an-array-at-a-specific-index) but, it did not explain how to insert to specified index of empty array.

Comment: Do you mean `a[3] = "item-3"`? This is not a good idea to do this though.

Comment: Why it is not good idea to do ? I mean of course there will be undefined items but other than that  is there any bad side ? @YeldarKurmangaliyev

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert an item into an array at a specific index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/how-to-insert-an-item-into-an-array-at-a-specific-index)

Comment: @ysnfrk Because this is not how an array is supposed to be used. If you do `var a = []; a[100000] = true;`, then `a.length` will be 100001. Also, most of algorithms rely on this length, which can cause many problems. Just use object \ set if you need key-value association array.

Comment: @ysnfrk have you got any approach for this. I would like to know about it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just use the index and do the assignment directly:

```js
var a = [];

a[3] = "item-3";

console.log(a);
```

Comment: *(As always: Hope my edit is helpful, but if not, please revert it.)*

Answer (score 6):

Coming in for the ES6 solution:

```
[...Array(3), 'item-3']
// [undefined, undefined, undefined, "item-3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the value to the index like this:

```js
var a = [];

a[3] = "item-3"; //3 is the index

console.log(a);
```