# How to insert an object into a specific index. Splice is not working for me

Tags: javascript

I tried replacing my elements specifically with an object. But it is just adding up like a push and making the array longer.

```
let arr = [];

function addToArray(index){
    let comment = value;
    let score= scoreType;
    let scorenow = score;
    let id = id;

    arr.splice(index,0,{comment,score,scorenow ,id });
}
```

I am figuring out a way to insert this object only to the index of arr.

Example : addToArray(2) should return a [undefined,undefined,{comment,score,scorenow,id}]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert an item into an empty array at a specific index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54038872/how-to-insert-an-item-into-an-empty-array-at-a-specific-index)

Comment: Splice doesn't work that way, it only adds to existing spaces or to the end of the array. You can manually increase its length and fill it with `undefined`

Comment: Incidentally, where are `value`, `scoreType`, `id`, and `score` coming from?

Comment: Also, why not just push the object into the array and then, if you need to locate it, use `find` or `findIndex` on the array to identify the object by `id`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this syntax:

```js
let arr = [];

function addToArray(index){
    let comment = 1;
    let score= 2;
    let scorenow = 3;
    let id = 4;

    arr[index] = { comment, score, scorenow, id };
}

addToArray(2);

console.log(arr);
```

If you want to do it with splice method you have to define the arr length first:

```js
let arr = [];

function addToArray(index){
    let comment = 1;
    let score= 2;
    let scorenow = 3;
    let id = 4;

    arr.length = index;
    arr.splice(index, 0, { comment, score, scorenow, id });
}

addToArray(2);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This overrides existing values in the index

Comment: That is something I want. But it is just pushing.

Comment: @sonEtLumiere Thanks a lot.. But may I know why the splice procedure failed ?

Comment: See Eldar B's comment under your question @Ryuzaki.

Comment: @Ryuzaki answer updated, check out how you can do it with splice method

Comment: @Andy For me that didn't happened. That why I asked this questions

Answer (score -1):

try this instead :

```
arr.splice(index,1,{comment,score,scorenow ,id });
```

putting 1 instead of 0 will replace the specific element , not appending a new one