# Sorting array of objects with some elements grouped

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have the next array:

```
const links = [
    { link: "google", sort: 0 },
    { link: "facebook", sort: 1 },
    { link: "ios", sort: 2 },
    { link: "android", sort: 3 },
    { link: "twitter", sort: 4 },
]
```

First thing I need is to change positions of elements. I did this with:

```
const linkName = "twitter";
const sort = 1;
const currentIndex = links.findIndex((e) => e.link == linkName);
links.splice(sort, 0, links.splice(currentIndex, 1)[0]);
links.map((e, i) => {
    e.sort = i;
});
/* modified array:
[
  { link: 'google', sort: 0 },
  { link: 'twitter', sort: 1 },
  { link: 'facebook', sort: 2 },
  { link: 'ios', sort: 3 },
  { link: 'android', sort: 4 }
]
*/
```

After this, twitter should be moved to index 1, and everything else should move one sort.

What I need is to keep "android" and "ios" in some sort of group. So those 2 would have the same sort. I want to end up with next array:

```
[
    { link: "google", sort: 0 },
    { link: "facebook", sort: 1 },
    { link: "ios", sort: 2 },
    { link: "android", sort: 2 },
    { link: "twitter", sort: 3 },
]
```

And for example, if I receive I want to move "ios" OR "android" to 0 index, it should look like this:

```
[
    { link: "ios", sort: 0 },
    { link: "android", sort: 0 },
    { link: "google", sort: 1 },
    { link: "facebook", sort: 2 },
    { link: "twitter", sort: 3 },
]
```

And if I want to move them to index 1, then it should look like this:

```
[
    { link: "google", sort: 0 },
    { link: "ios", sort: 1 },
    { link: "android", sort: 1 },
    { link: "facebook", sort: 2 },
    { link: "twitter", sort: 3 },
]
```

Comment: So if you want to move to position 1, then whatever IS at position 1 gets to be its position-1?

Comment: Why not just have two arrays? One for social and one for platform?

Comment: There are a number of different structures in which you could store this kind of data that would make this type of operation less cumbersome, are you open to changing the structure of the data?

Comment: @mplungjan actually, it should be its position + 1... Consider this like drag&drop... If you move something up, everything else below that position should be moved below.

Comment: @HereticMonkey what do you have in mind? Currently, I store this data in mongodb, and on frontend its drag&drop.. And on frontend its hardcoded that android&ios have the same box...

Comment: Well, what's the point of keeping android and ios separate? Just lump them together (on the backend) as "mobileos" or something. That's one problem off the table. Then all you have is an ordered array of objects, and you just use the position of the object in the array as the `sort`, and use array functions to move things around. If the user drags an item to the top, `splice` from the array, `unshift` it to the beginning. If the user drags it to the second place, `splice` from the array, [then use `slice`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55751754/215552). To the end? `splice` and `push`.

Comment: Since I'm holding this in MongoDB, each of those objects in array are actually documents in collection. And beside that, I have some other info... That's why I need them to be separated I mean, I could temporarily group them, but in the end, I should get that array of objects I wrote in question.