# How insert a object inbetween 2 object in an array with ES6/Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const data = [
 {name:'Apple', order:1, path:'0'}
 {name: 'Orange', order:2, path:'1'}
 {name: 'Banana', order:3, path:'2'}
 {name: 'Grape', order:4, path:'3'}
]

const newObj = {name: 'Mango', order:3, path:'2'}
```

I want to insert the new object data in the '**data**' array in between the '**Orange**' - '**Banana**' and also change the **order** values and **path** values based on the new object order and path value.

I mean based on the new object path and order value the new object will insert the correct position.

the answer is like below:-

```
const data = [
 {name:'Apple', order:1, path:'0'}
 {name: 'Orange', order:2, path:'1'}
 {name: 'Mango', order:3, path:'2'}
 {name: 'Banana', order:4, path:'3'}
 {name: 'Grape', order:5, path:'4'}
]
```

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/how-to-insert-an-item-into-an-array-at-a-specific-index-javascript) but I want to increase my object order and path count.

Comment: Are your objects supposed to have colons instead of `=` and commas between them?

Comment: Sorry, I updated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert an object using [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and then update each item by using a for loop to update only the elements after the insert (since only those elements' order will change):

```js
const data = [
 {name:'Apple', order:1, path:'0'},
 {name: 'Orange', order:2, path:'1'},
 {name: 'Banana', order:3, path:'2'},
 {name: 'Grape', order:4, path:'3'}
];
const newObj = {name: 'Mango', order:3, path:'2'}

data.splice(newObj.path, 0, newObj);
for (let i = newObj.order; i < data.length; i++) { // update order of elements after inserted element
    data[i].order += 1; // update order
    data[i].path = `${i}`; // update path
}
console.log(data);
```

Comment: @imjayabal I added an edit to incorporate the `path` change as well

Comment: @imjayabal Also, you can use `map` or `forEach` like you suggested in your edit, which I had actually originally done, but there's no need to iterate over the elements before the inserted item, since their order and path won't change, so I did it like this to make it a bit faster in case it's a large array