# Angular push key to array position

Tags: arrays, angular

I try to arrange my array. This is how it looks like:

```
0: Object { row: 0 }
1: Object { row: 1 }
2: Object { row: 2 }
3: Object { row: 3 }
```

I want to add a new key now to position 2. Should look like this:

```
0: Object { row: 0 }
1: Object { row: 1 }
2: Object { row: 2,newkey: 2 }
3: Object { row: 3 }
```

I found out how to put in right position, but not how to arrange array with new key?

Comment: Did you tried `arr[2].newKey=2`

Comment: This is a duplicate of  [How to insert an item into an array at a specific index (JavaScript)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/how-to-insert-an-item-into-an-array-at-a-specific-index-javascript)

Comment: I thought that @SagarV but it looks like they are trying to add a key to an existing item

Comment: @Matt oh ok. he edited his question. My answer is for first version.

Comment: Yeah I also left an answer for the first version! Glad I'm not going crazy.

Comment: SaschaK, if you are trying to add a new key to the object at position 2, use: `yourArray[2].newkey = 2;`

Comment: @Matt thank you so much! Can key be deleted, too?

Comment: Yep you can use `delete yourArray[2].newkey;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> yourArray[2]['newKey'] = 2

`yourArray[2].newKey` like suggested in the comments may throw an error since the property newKey doesn't exist in the object.

Comment: That won't error, the property doesn't have to exist to be assigned

Answer (score 0):

To assign a new key:

`yourArray[2].newkey = 2;`

To delete a key:

`delete yourArray[2].newkey;`