# Array=[3,4,5,6,7,6,7]. Temp=[1,2] how to store the value of temp in the array's 5th and 6th index in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
Array=[3,4,5,6,7,6,7]
Temp=[1,2]
```

how to store the value of temp in the array's 5th and 6th index in JavaScript

Comment: I think you're looking for `splice` method. Look at this [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: should the result be [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 6, 7] or should it replace the old values at the indicies?

Comment: Array.splice(5, 0, ...Temp);

Answer (score 0):

Use the **array.splice** function
`arr.splice(index, 0, item);` will insert item into arr at the specified index (deleting 0 items first, that is, it's just an insert).

This in combination with **...array** to insert the values of the array instead of the array itself

```js
let Array=[3,4,5,6,7,6,7];
console.log(Array);

let Temp=[1,2]
Array.splice(5, 0, ...Temp);

console.log(Array);
```

Refering this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/how-to-insert-an-item-into-an-array-at-a-specific-index-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

`splice` not only deletes items. You can also use it to **insert** items into the array.
To effectively "spread" `temp`, you need the **spread operator**:

```js
array.splice(5, 0, ...temp);
```

Then you can reuse `splice` to delete the old items:

```js
array.splice(7, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `splice`, but it would mutate your original array

For safer use, make the result in the whole new array without affecting the original one, here I suggest using `slice`

```js
const array=[3,4,5,6,7,6,7]
const temp=[1,2]
const res = [array.slice(0, 5), temp, array.slice(5)].flat()

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [3,4,5,6,7,6,7];
const temp = [1, 2];
const res = [...arr.slice(0, 5), ...temp, ...arr.slice(5)];
console.log(res);
```

You can destructure the first part from your array until index 5 and the rest like this, you don't need to use `.flat()` to flatten the array.