# Return modified array after adding one element at certain position

Tags: javascript

Is there any function which **inserts value at certain index** and **returns modified array** like `filter` or `map`?

I already tried `array.splice(item, 0, index)` but it returns `[]` instead of modified array

Comment: Maybe the OP is going to have a second look at the [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#syntax) and the [return value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#return_value) of `splice`.

Comment: No, there is no in-built function that does this, so you'll have to implement it yourself (`splice` makes this straightforward).

Comment: the main question is: do you want a new array or the same array?

Comment: Apart from any solutions mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/how-to-insert-an-item-into-an-array-at-a-specific-index-javascript), i'd be interested in one, which returns a new array with the element inserted, but doesn't copy the array more than once, doesn't have a function call per element, etc. Just a very low level immutable element insert. I know a `for` loop would do, but adding to native prototypes is kind of a no-no, and a native engine implementation would also be faster anyways.

Comment: I want a new array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a value at an index by returning two values at an index with [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```js
const
    array = [1, 2, 4, 5],
    index = 2,
    newValue = 3,
    newArray = array.flatMap((v, i) => i === index ? [newValue, v] : v);

console.log(...newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can add your own function using `Array.prototype`:

```js
const arr = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

Array.prototype.spliceReturn = function(idx, val) {
  this.splice(idx, 0, val)
  return this
}
let res = arr.spliceReturn(1, 'biz')
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add to the array using [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and return it:

```js
const insert = (arr, index, val) => {
  arr.splice(index, 0, val);
  return arr;
}

console.log( insert([0,1,3], 2, 2) );
```

Answer (score 1):

The next approach handles array items more flexible, be it just a single item or even multiple ones. It meets both acceptance criteria, the one of the OP and the one of ***ASDFGerte*** ...

```js
function newArrayFromInsertItems(arr, idx, ...items) {
  arr = Array.from(arr ?? []);
  arr.splice(idx, 0, ...items);
  return arr;
}

const arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

console.log(
  "newArrayFromInsertItems(arr, 1, 'buz') ...",
  newArrayFromInsertItems(arr, 1, 'buz')
);
console.log(
  "newArrayFromInsertItems(arr, 1, 'biz', 'buz') ...",
  newArrayFromInsertItems(arr, 1, 'biz', 'buz')
);
console.log(
  "newArrayFromInsertItems(arr, 2, ['bar', 'baz'], 'biz') ...",
  newArrayFromInsertItems(arr, 2, ['bar', 'baz'], 'biz')
);
console.log('arr ...', arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[1, 2, 4].toSpliced(2, 0, 3) // returns a new array, [1, 2, 3, 4].
```

Check out the documentation for [Array.prototype.toSpliced()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSpliced).