# How can I sort the given array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
let Card=['Primary',Secondary,'Abccc','BBC','DDC']
```

How can I sort the given array based on where if the array contains the Values 'Primary' and 'Secondary', we need to order in such way that "Primary" is on top and "Secondary" below that irrespective of the casing?

I just have an array which has dynamic data  and incase the values 'Primary' or 'Secondary' comes in the array then I need to push the 'Primary' to 0 index and 'Secondary' to 1 index of the array.

Comment: It is easy to help you if you can provide your exact requirement with the code

Comment: Are you sure an array is the best solution for you rather than an object?

Comment: For the first position you can use Unshift and for the specific index you can read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/how-to-insert-an-item-into-an-array-at-a-specific-index-javascript

Answer (score 0):

This works

```js
let Card=['Primary','Secondary','Abccc','BBC','DDC'].sort(() => Math.random()*2 - 1)
console.log(Card.join());
Card.sort((a, b) => {
  if ( a === 'Primary' ) return -1;
  if ( b === 'Primary' ) return 1;
  if ( a === 'Secondary' ) return -1;
  if ( b === 'Secondary' ) return 1;
  return a.localeCompare(b);
});
console.log(Card.join());
```

Comment: oops, hang on - I fuxored it up :p - there - NOW it works like you want

Comment: it is giving an error localeCompare is not a function

Comment: so, when you click the "Run Code Snippet" button, you get that error @rockrake

Comment: then you wrote your code differently to what you presented in the question ... are ALL values in `Card` strings? actual strings, real strings?