# How to Insert JSON into array's before last item?

Tags: javascript, arrays, insert

I want to build a function that will always insert `JSON Items` in an array at the `last` item before.

```
const array = [ 
  {India: { Score: '12', PlayedMatched: '21' } },
  { China: { Score: '52', PlayedMatched: '51' }},
  { USA: { Score: '15', PlayedMatched: '06' } },
  // Insert Items Here
  { 'Index Value': 12 }      
]

const insert = (arr, index, newItem) => [
    ...arr.slice(0, index),
    newItem,
    ...arr.slice(index)
]


var insertItems= [{ 'Japan': { Score: "54", PlayedMatched: "56" } },{ 'Russia': { Score: "99", PlayedMatched: "178" } }];

// I have tried like this: array.slice(-1) to insert item one step before always

const result = insert(array,array.slice(-1),insertItems)

console.log(result);
```

**OutPut:**

```
[ [ { Japan: [Object] }, { Japan: [Object] } ],     //Not at Here
  { India: { Score: '12', PlayedMatched: '21' } },
  { China: { Score: '52', PlayedMatched: '51' } },
  { USA: { Score: '15', PlayedMatched: '06' } },
  { 'Index Value': 12 } ]
```

---

**Expected Output:**

```
[ 
  { India: { Score: '12', PlayedMatched: '21' } },
  { China: { Score: '52', PlayedMatched: '51' } },
  { USA: { Score: '15', PlayedMatched: '06' } },
  [ { Japan: [Object] }, { Japan: [Object] } ],      //At here
  { 'Index Value': 12 }
]
```

How should i do this? And I also want to remove the this: `[]` in my Output Results. :)

**Like This:**

```
 [ 
  {India: { Score: '12', PlayedMatched: '21' } },
  { China: { Score: '52', PlayedMatched: '51' }},
  { USA: { Score: '15', PlayedMatched: '06' } },
  { 'Japan': { Score: "54", PlayedMatched: "56" } },
  { 'Russia': { Score: "99", PlayedMatched: "178" } },
  { 'Index Value': 12 }      
]
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but `{India: { Score: '12', PlayedMatched: '21' } },` doesn't seem like a very usable object structure to me. `{team: "India", score: 12, playedMatches: 21}` makes more sense to me, so you needn't do `Object.keys` or something just to figure out what team it is. Or consider an outer object keyed by team name rather than an array.

Comment: There is nothing related to JSON in your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert an item into an array at a specific index (JavaScript)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/how-to-insert-an-item-into-an-array-at-a-specific-index-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Use the splice function like so:

```
const array = [ 
  {India: { Score: '12', PlayedMatched: '21' } },
  { China: { Score: '52', PlayedMatched: '51' }},
  { USA: { Score: '15', PlayedMatched: '06' } },
  { 'Index Value': 12 }      
]


var insertItems= [{ 'Japan': { Score: "54", PlayedMatched: "56" } },{ 'Russia': { Score: "99", PlayedMatched: "178" } }];



array.splice(array.length - 1, 0, ...insertItems)

console.log(array);
```

Notice that splice modify the same array you give it and doesn't create a modified copy of it.

Comment: I was going to post the same thing with a snippet, but I'll refrain. Pls consider rounding out your answer with OP's code and a testable snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the index number where you want to insert as `index` parameter in insert function to get the job done. In your case **last second place** so, you can pass `array.length - 1`

```
const array = [ 
  {India: { Score: '12', PlayedMatched: '21' } },
  { China: { Score: '52', PlayedMatched: '51' }},
  { USA: { Score: '15', PlayedMatched: '06' } },
  { 'Index Value': 12 }      
]

const insert = (arr, index, newItem) => [
    ...arr.slice(0, index),
    ...newItem,
    ...arr.slice(index)
]


var insertItems= [{ 'Japan': { Score: "54", PlayedMatched: "56" } },{ 'Russia': { Score: "99", PlayedMatched: "178" } }];



const result = insert(array,array.length - 1,insertItems)

console.log(result);
```